# How can I get a random key-value pair from a dictionary?

Tags: python, random, dictionary, key

In Python, given a dictionary like

```
{
    'VENEZUELA': 'CARACAS',
    'CANADA': 'OTTAWA'
}
```

How can I choose a *random* item (key-value pair)?

What if I only need the key, or only the value - can it be optimized?

Answer (score 381, accepted):

[Make a list of the dictionary's items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695456), and choose randomly from that [in the usual way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400):

```
import random
d = {'VENEZUELA':'CARACAS', 'CANADA':'OTTAWA'}
country, capital = random.choice(list(d.items()))
```

Similarly, if only a value is needed, choose directly from the values:

```
capital = random.choice(list(d.values()))
```

Comment: To expand on Duncan's comment, you can also just do `random.choice([d.keys()])`. The brackets convert the iterator to a list just the same as calling `list()`, but it may look a bit cleaner for some.

Comment: Is this efficient? Does this scale if dict gets really large?

Comment: @code-法:  Depends on what you mean by *efficient*, and *large*.  A quick test shows it can pick a million random values out of a dictionary with a million entries in less than a second (assumes saving off the `d.keys()` part).  Is that efficient?

Comment: @Gerrat, do you know if the transformation of d.keys() from iterator to list if constant (k) or O(n)?

Comment: @toto_tico:  Changing an iterator to a list would be O(n)

Comment: @Seaux: brackets just make a one-item list whose item is the iterator itself.  They don't make a list whose items are the iterator's items.

Comment: @austingae: because `random.choice` takes sequence as the parameter (see [Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)) and dictionary isn't a sequence - you can't refer to its elements by index.

Comment: Careful: this answer does not seem to apply for complex keys (tuples, lists, and possibly other iterables). In that case: `index = random.choice(range(len(d)))` and work from there (remember order is only garantueed in OrderedDict).

Comment: @Seaux that does not work - it makes a list **of one item**, which is the entire keys-view. Did you mean `random.choice([*d.keys()])` (note the `*`)?

Comment: @David. I have no idea what leads you to this conclusion. Lists can't be used as keys at all in the first place, and tuple keys work just fine with this code. Also, there is no reason why we should care about the key order when *the goal is to choose randomly*.

Answer (score 15):

Call [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) on the keys of the dictionary (the countries).

In 2.x, the `keys` can be chosen from directly:

```
>>> import random
>>> d = dict(Venezuela = 1, Spain = 2, USA = 3, Italy = 4)
>>> random.choice(d.keys())
'Venezuela'
>>> random.choice(d.keys())
'USA'
```

In 3.x, create a list first, e.g. `random.choice(list(d.keys()))`.

Comment: Hi, I try to use your method to randomly pick one key from a given dictionary, but it does not work. My dictionary looks like a = {'walk': 20, 'run': 80} and when I use random.choice(a.keys()), there is an error like "dict_keys' object does not support indexing". Do you know what's wrong? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @beepretty dict.keys() returns an iterable object, not a list-like object. To resolve the error, use `random.choice(list(d.keys()))`.

Comment: Use random.sample instead, which is cheaper than copying the keys to a list.

Comment: @steveayre No, `random.sample` doesn't work with dict input.

Comment: Choice's docstring now helpfully recommends wrapping the dict with sorted(), which is fine if done once on creation of the dictionary.

Answer (score 13):

Give a dictionary `a`, use:

```
import random
random_key = random.sample(a.keys(), 1)[0]
```

Comment: `TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).`

Comment: `random_key = random.sample(a.keys(), 1)[0]` does work, however.

Comment: @wim I can't easily check right now, but I think it worked with just `a` in 2.x. (Also, it's a little disconcerting that the exception message hard-codes a variable name not present in the code.)

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to use the `random` module, you can also try [popitem()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem):

```
>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 7}
>>> d.popitem()
('a', 1)
>>> d
{'c': 7, 'b': 5}
>>> d.popitem()
('c', 7)
```

Since the `dict` [doesn't preserve order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526131), by using `popitem` you get items in an arbitrary (but not strictly random) order from it.

Also keep in mind that `popitem` removes the key-value pair from dictionary, as stated in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem).

> popitem() is useful to destructively iterate over a dictionary

Comment: This is kind of bad, because if you load the dictionary in the same order on the same version of python you'll almost certainly get the same item.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593651/pythonic-way-to-access-arbitrary-element-from-dictionary

Comment: python 3.6 dict is actually *ORDERED*! This is super important

Comment: This answer is just wrong. Even before 3.6 this will not give you a random value, but a value depending on the hash value ot the item.

Comment: Ignoring the incongruity with the OP's request, this way is a good way to get over the fact that `next` does not work with a dictionary as it is a mapping. (I came here for inspiration and this was it).

Comment: `popitem()` would only return a random item, when you `shuffle` the `dict` first or you are somehow sure that it is already in random order.

Comment: @MatteoFerla `next` works perfectly well with a dictionary *iterator*, which can easily be created by calling `iter` on the dictionary. This is how `for k in my_dict:` can work.

Answer (score 8):

This works in Python 2 and Python 3:

A random key:

```
random.choice(list(d.keys()))
```

A random value

```
random.choice(list(d.values()))
```

A random key and value

```
random.choice(list(d.items()))
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the original post wanted the **pair**:

```
import random
d = {'VENEZUELA':'CARACAS', 'CANADA':'TORONTO'}
country, capital = random.choice(list(d.items()))
```

(python 3 style)

Answer (score 3):

To get a random key, use `random.choice()`, passing the dictionary keys like so:

```
import random
keys = list(my_dict)
country = random.choice(keys)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are separate functions to get a key, value or item:

```
import random

def pick_random_key_from_dict(d: dict):
    """Grab a random key from a dictionary."""
    keys = list(d.keys())
    random_key = random.choice(keys)
    return random_key

def pick_random_item_from_dict(d: dict):
    """Grab a random item from a dictionary."""
    random_key = pick_random_key_from_dict(d)
    random_item = random_key, d[random_key]
    return random_item

def pick_random_value_from_dict(d: dict):
    """Grab a random value from a dictionary."""
    _, random_value = pick_random_item_from_dict(d)
    return random_value
```

These can be used like:

```
d = {...}
random_item = pick_random_item_from_dict(d)
```

These approaches only copy the keys of the dict, mitigating the need to copy the data in order to use `random.choice`. Once we have the key, we can get the corresponding value, and thus an item.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use random.choice() you can try this way:

```
>>> list(myDictionary)[i]
'VENEZUELA'
>>> myDictionary = {'VENEZUELA':'CARACAS', 'IRAN' : 'TEHRAN'}
>>> import random
>>> i = random.randint(0, len(myDictionary) - 1)
>>> myDictionary[list(myDictionary)[i]]
'TEHRAN'
>>> list(myDictionary)[i]
'IRAN'
```

Comment: Pay attention: you generate a `list(…)` here multiple times. How about `myDictionary_list = list(myDictionary)`?

Comment: While possible, the entire reason `random.choice` exists is in order to avoid the need to generate and use a random index.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework:

Check out [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) which will select and return a random element from an list. You can get a list of dictionary keys with `dict.keys()` and a list of dictionary values with `dict.values()`.

Comment: `random.sample` and `random.choice` can't work with iterators.  They need to know the length of the sequence, which can't be determined from an iterator.

Comment: `random.sample` returns `k` random _elements_, `random.choice` returns a single random element

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are making a quiz kind of application. For this kind of application I have written a function which is as follows:

```
def shuffle(q):
"""
The input of the function will 
be the dictionary of the question
and answers. The output will
be a random question with answer
"""
selected_keys = []
i = 0
while i < len(q):
    current_selection = random.choice(q.keys())
    if current_selection not in selected_keys:
        selected_keys.append(current_selection)
        i = i+1
        print(current_selection+'? '+str(q[current_selection]))
```

If I will give the input of `questions = {'VENEZUELA':'CARACAS', 'CANADA':'TORONTO'}` and call the function `shuffle(questions)` Then the output will be as follows:

```
VENEZUELA? CARACAS
CANADA? TORONTO
```

You can extend this further more by shuffling the options also

Comment: You should not program drawing without replacement like this. Imagine drawing the 100th of 100 elements - 99% chance to hit an element inside of `selected_keys`. And you will likely repeat that about 100 times. 
At least delete the taken keys of q like `del(q[current_selection])` - you can overwrite q with the new shuffled `selected_keys` just like `q = selected_keys` after everything. Also don't forget about identing! Alternatively look at my `np.random.choice(...)` approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62843377/4575793

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x, the objects returned by methods `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()` are [view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), which cannot be used directly with `random.choice`.

One option is to pass `random.choice` a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that extracts the candidate values to choose from:

```py
import random

colors = {
    'purple': '#7A4198',
    'turquoise': '#9ACBC9',
    'orange': '#EF5C35',
    'blue': '#19457D',
    'green': '#5AF9B5',
    'red': ' #E04160',
    'yellow': '#F9F985'
}

color = random.choice([color_value for color_value in colors.values()]

print(f'The new color is: {color}')
```

Comment: This is redundant with prior answers; the list comprehension is simply a long-winded (and slower) way to get a list from the view.

Answer (score 0):

To select 50 random key values from a dictionary set `dict_data`:

```
sample = random.sample(set(dict_data.keys()), 50)
```

Comment: Sampling from a set deprecated since Python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

I needed to iterate through ranges of keys in a `dict` *without sorting it each time* and found the [Sorted Containers](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) library. I discovered that this library enables random access to dictionary items by index which solves this problem intuitively and **without iterating through the entire `dict` each time:**

```
>>> import sortedcontainers
>>> import random
>>> d = sortedcontainers.SortedDict({1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'})
>>> random.choice(d.items())
(1, 'a')
>>> random.sample(d.keys(), k=2)
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Note that this is _O(log n)_ runtime complexity, not _O(1)_.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (using random.choice from items)

```
import random

a={ "str" : "sda" , "number" : 123, 55 : "num"}
random.choice(list(a.items()))
#  ('str', 'sda')
random.choice(list(a.items()))[1] # getting a value
#  'num'
```

Comment: How does this add anything above all the previous existing answers?

Answer (score -2):

I found this post by looking for a rather comparable solution. For picking multiple elements out of a dict, this can be used:

```
idx_picks = np.random.choice(len(d), num_of_picks, replace=False) #(Don't pick the same element twice)
result = dict ()
c_keys = [d.keys()] #not so efficient - unfortunately .keys() returns a non-indexable object because dicts are unordered
for i in idx_picks:
    result[c_keys[i]] = d[i]
```

Comment: `[d.keys()]` does not do what you want here.

Answer (score -3):

```
b = { 'video':0, 'music':23,"picture":12 } 
random.choice(tuple(b.items())) ('music', 23) 
random.choice(tuple(b.items())) ('music', 23) 
random.choice(tuple(b.items())) ('picture', 12) 
random.choice(tuple(b.items())) ('video', 0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a little Python code for a dictionary class that can return random keys in O(1) time. (I included MyPy types in this code for readability):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Dict, List
import random

K = TypeVar('K')
V = TypeVar('V')
class IndexableDict(Generic[K, V]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.keys: List[K] = []
        self.vals: List[V] = []
        self.dict: Dict[K, int] = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key: K) -> V:
        return self.vals[self.dict[key]]

    def __setitem__(self, key: K, val: V) -> None:
        if key in self.dict:
            index = self.dict[key]
            self.vals[index] = val
        else:
            self.dict[key] = len(self.keys)
            self.keys.append(key)
            self.vals.append(val)

    def __contains__(self, key: K) -> bool:
        return key in self.dict

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.keys)

    def random_key(self) -> K:
        return self.keys[random.randrange(len(self.keys))]
```

Comment: Popping values take O(N) though. It is not optimal to maintain 2 lists to hold the same values of the dictionary.

Comment: Popping could be done efficiently by swapping with the last element before removing it.