# How can I get a weighted random pick from Python's Counter class?

Tags: python, random, iterator, counter, weighted

I have a program where I'm keeping track of the success of various *things* using `collections.Counter` — each success of a *thing* increments the corresponding counter:

```
import collections
scoreboard = collections.Counter()

if test(thing):
    scoreboard[thing]+ = 1
```

Then, for future tests, I want to skew towards *things* which have generated the most success. `Counter.elements()` seemed ideal for this, since it returns the elements (in arbitrary order) repeated a number of times equal to the count. So I figured I could just do:

```
import random
nextthing=random.choice(scoreboard.elements())
```

But no, that raises **TypeError: object of type 'itertools.chain' has no len()**. Okay, so [`random.choice` can't work with iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859328/479426). But, in this case, the length is known (or knowable) — it's `sum(scoreboard.values())`.

I know the basic algorithm for iterating through a list of unknown length and fairly picking an element at random, but I suspect that there's something more elegant. What should I be doing here?

Comment: How about just turning `scoreboard.elements()` into a list?

Comment: @delnan — see comment on [larsks's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9084700/479426) below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this rather easily by using [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get the Nth item of an iterable:

```
>>> import random
>>> import itertools
>>> import collections
>>> c = collections.Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1})
>>> i = random.randrange(sum(c.values()))
>>> next(itertools.islice(c.elements(), i, None))
'a'
```

Comment: Is there a way to directly calculate the item rather than iterating through `i-1` elements?  If c has small values, that's not a problem, but if one or more of the keys has a very high count, it will take a long time to iterate.

Comment: As @BrianMinton hints, this has a worst-case runtime proportional to the sum of the counts in the Counter. If the counts are large, this will be super slow.

Answer (score 7):

Given a dictionary of choices with corresponding relative probabilities (can be the count in your case), you can use the new [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choices) added in Python 3.6 like so:

```py
import random

my_dict = {
    "choice a" : 1, # will in this case be chosen 1/3 of the time
    "choice b" : 2, # will in this case be chosen 2/3 of the time
}

choice = random.choices(*zip(*my_dict.items()))[0]
```

For your code that uses `Counter`, you can do the same thing, because `Counter` also has the `items()` getter.

```py
import collections
import random

my_dict = collections.Counter(a=1, b=2, c=3)
choice = random.choices(*zip(*my_dict.items()))[0]
```

Explanation: `my_dict.items()` is `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]`.
So `zip(*my_dict.items())` is `[('a', 'b', 'c'), (1, 2, 3)]`.
And `random.choices(('a', 'b', 'c'), (1, 2, 3))` is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the iterator in `list()` to convert it into a list for `random.choice()`:

```
nextthing = random.choice(list(scoreboard.elements()))
```

The downside here is that this expands the list in memory, rather than accessing it item-by-item as would normally get with an iterator.

If you wanted to solve this iteratively, [this algorithm](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1910) is probably a good choice.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to avoid exploding the count into a gigantic list. Doing that negates the advantage of using `Counter` rather than just piling everything into a big container in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The following will get a random item where the score is the weighting for how often to return that item.

```
import random

def get_random_item_weighted(scoreboard):    
    total_scoreboard_value = sum(scoreboard.values())

    item_loc = random.random() * total_scoreboard_value
    current_loc = 0
    for item, score in scoreboard.items():
        current_loc += score
        if current_loc > item_loc:
            return item
```

for instance, if there are 2 items:

item1 has a score 5
item2 has a score 10

item2 will be returned twice as often as item1

Answer (score 2):

Another variant, 
Setup is a bit cumbersome, but lookup is in logarithmic complexity (suitable when several lookups are needed):

```
import itertools
import random
from collections import Counter
from bisect import bisect

counter = Counter({"a": 5, "b": 1, "c": 1})

#setup
most_common = counter.most_common()
accumulated = list(itertools.accumulate([x[1] for x in most_common])) # i.e. [5, 6, 7]
total_size = accumulated[-1]

# lookup
i = random.randrange(total_size)
print(most_common[bisect(accumulated, i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant with iteration:

```
import collections
from collections import Counter
import random


class CounterElementsRandomAccess(collections.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, counter):
        self._counter = counter

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(self._counter.values())

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        for i, el in enumerate(self._counter.elements()):
            if i == item:
                return el

scoreboard = Counter('AAAASDFQWERQWEQWREAAAAABBBBCCDDVBSDF')
score_elements = CounterElementsRandomAccess(scoreboard)
for i in range(10):
    print random.choice(score_elements)
```

Comment: This is broken for non-integer counts and inefficient for very large counts, both of which are legal.