# Mapping elements of a list to Intervals to create a cumulative probability distribution

Tags: python, distribution, probability, cdf

I have a list of elements, for example `L = [A, B, C]`. Each element has an associated score for example `S = [5, 1, 4]`.

I want to select an element from L according to its score in S, simply by generating a sort of cumulative probability distribution, where each element `L[i]` corresponds to an interval in `(0,1]` proportional to `S[i]`. Then, a random number drawn in (0,1] maps to the selected element.

For the example given before, we can have the scores of `S` represented as probabilities by normalizing on `5+1+4` so we get `SS = [0.5, 0.1, 0.4]`, and we map the elements of `L` to intervals, such that:

```
B is mapped to (0, 0.1]
C is mapped to (0.1, 0.1+0.4]
A is mapped to (0.1+0.4, 0.5+0.5]
```

Now if I generate a random number `r` in (0,1] (e.g. `r = random.random()`), it will map to the corresponding element. For example if `r = 0.03` we know that the element is B. And for instance, if `r = 0.73` we know that the element is A ...

Is there a simple way in python to do this mapping between an element and an interval ?

I know that I can use `numpy.cumsum` to generate the cumulative sum of SS, but how to map elements to intervals obtained from this cumulative sum ?

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to have a list such that when a random number is generated, a corresponding element of the list is returned?

Comment: Let me check if I understand correctly. You want to generate arbitrary discrete random variates defined by a cdf from a uniform distribution?

Comment: @JoelCornett no that is not what I want to do. I just want to create a CDF based on a list of elements and a scores/probabilities. So that we can select randomly an element according to that CDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, I would recommend a `dict`:

```
def branchFinder(L, S, r):
    S, L = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(S, L))))
    SS = [0.] + map(lambda x: x/10., S)

    probs = {}
    for i in range(len(L)):
        probs[L[i]] = (sum(SS[:i+1]), SS[i+1] + sum(SS[:i+1]))        

    for key, value in probs.iteritems():
        if value[0] < r <= value[1]:
             return key
```

Comment: If the values are ordered, (as they would be in a CDF) there is no need to do the first less than comparison.

Comment: @JoelCornett the values might be ordered *into* the dictionary, but not necessarily out of it!

Comment: I'm not sure which value you're referring to.  If you mean the values of ```value``` then you must do both comparisons because they're in a ```dict``` which is unordered by its nature

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Which would imply that a `dict` might not be the best way to store the CDF ;)

Comment: How do you construct the dict `probs` from `L` and `SS` ?

Comment: @shn, I'll update on how that's done, give me a minute

Comment: @shn, I've updated it so the function now takes ```L``` and ```S``` as its arguments, then generates ```probs```  based on those.  Let me know if this is what you want

Comment: I get an error. for key, value in probs: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: It is ok, fixed using: `for key, value in probs.iteritems()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(dict(zip(L, S)))
```

Giving, e.g.:

```
Counter({'A': 5, 'C': 4, 'B': 1})
```

Then use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084647/how-can-i-get-a-weighted-random-pick-from-pythons-counter-class) to randomly select from it:

```
from random import randrange
from itertools import islice

index = randrange(sum(counts.values()))
next(islice(counts.elements(), index, None))
```

or just choose from the list (perhaps clearer what's happening, but less efficient with big lists):

```
from random import choice

choice(list(counts.elements()))
```

This doesn't answer your exact question (generating probabilities), but hopefully gets you the result you need (random selection based on score).