# Why does Python 3 need dict.items to be wrapped with list()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

I'm using Python 3. I've just installed a Python IDE and I am curious about the following code warning:

```
features = { ... }
for k, v in features.items():
    print("%s=%s" % (k, v))
```

Warning is: *"For Python3 support should look like ... `list(features.items())` "*

Also there is mention about this at http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#fixers

> It also wraps existing usages of dict.items(), dict.keys(), and dict.values() in a call to list.

Why is this necessary?

Comment: I think that your IDE should instead warn you that `'{}={}'.format(k, v)` is recommended instead. :) Reference: http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changes-already-present-in-python-2-6

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can safely ignore this "extra precautions" warning: your code will work the same *even without `list`* in both versions of Python. It would run differently if you needed a list (but this is not the case): in fact, `features.items()` is a *list* in Python 2, but a *[view](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)* in Python 3. They work the same when used as an iterable, as in your example.

Now, the Python 2 to Python 3 conversion tool `2to3` errs on the side of safety, and assumes that you really wanted a *list* when you use `dict.items()`. This may not be the case (as in the question), in which case `dict.items()` in Python 3 (no wrapping `list`) is better (faster, and less memory-consuming, since no list is built).

Concretely, this means that Python 2 code can explicitly iterate over the view: `for k, v in features.viewitems()` (which will be converted in Python 3 by `2to3` to `features.items()`). It looks like your IDE thinks that the code is Python 2, because your `for` statement is very good, in Python 3, so there should be no warning about Python 3 support.

Comment: Note: in general, it is *not* safe to ignore the warning if the loop modifies the dict. It  breaks on Python 3 without `list()`.

Comment: This should never happen: a loop normally *cannot modify the dictionary it is iterating over*; this generally raises a `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` (both in Python 2 and Python 3). Reference: http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-3106-dictionary-views

Comment: `d.items()` returns a list on Python 2 therefore the loop *can* modify the dictionary. Just try it: `d = {1:2}; for k, v in d.items(): d[3]=4` - this code works on Python 2 but it breaks on Python 3 with the error that you've mentioned.

Comment: Indeed. I had the likes of `my_dict.iteritems()` in mind (which does raise the exception I mentioned, even in Python 2): in the case you cite, one is not "iterating over the dictionary" but over a list, as you say. That said, now I see what you meant: that `list()` is necessary in Python 3 if one wants to modify the dictionary. I had missed this because (1) the warning is actually a little strange, as the for loop statement is perfect Python 3 code; and (2) this is a relatively rare situation (never modified a dictionary after items() in 7 years!). Good point. :)

Comment: This doesn't explain why a `list` is necessary, which is required by the _main_ question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? The answer to the original question is that `list()` is _not_ necessary. A longer answer is that if the `features` dictionary of the original question were modified in the loop, then `list()` would effectively freeze the list of items and the dictionary could be modified in the loop (iterating over a view of the items in a dictionary that changes may raise an exception).

Comment: The key phrase in this answer is `when used as an iterable`

Comment: I know this is an old post but I just wanted to point out that having to wrap every `items()` call in a list feels extremely not pythonic.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? There is no need to do this in Python 2, and in Python 3, most of the time there isn't either. But when in Python you do need to obtain a list from the items, then you have to wrap them in `list()` but this is by definition "Pythonic": it just means that you know that `items()` returns an iterable, and that if you want to build a list from it, Python lets you do it.

Answer (score 56):

In Python 2, the methods `items()`, `keys()` and `values()` used to "take a snapshot" of the dictionary contents and return it as a list. It meant that if the dictionary changed while you were iterating over the list, the contents in the list would *not* change.

In Python 3, these methods return a [view object](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) whose contents *change dynamically as the dictionary changes*. Therefore, in order for the behavior of iterations over the result of these methods to remain consistent with previous versions, an additional call to `list()` has to be performed in Python 3 to "take a snapshot" of the view object contents.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and (+1) of course, but this derive one more question on it: ... *change dynamically* ... If I'm ok with dynamic changes, do Python provides safe iteration over it (just compare with java behavior - raise exception from iterator on changing container)

Comment: @Dewfy, not really. The view objects themselves are safe, but as soon as you create iterators from them and use these iterators in loops, adding or removing entries from the source dictionary may lead to errors or "miss" entries. The documentation says `iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may raise a RuntimeError or fail to iterate over all entries`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it actually answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

Python 3 returns a [Dictionary View Object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) rather than a list which Python 2 would return and some operators that you would expect may not be true - also a View Object will change if the underlying dictionary changes, (possibly in the code that you are iterating through which could cause some unwelcome surprises).

Answer (score 3):

<s>In Python 3, `dict.items()`, `dict.keys()`, and `dict.values()` are iterators. Therefore if you are expecting a list, you might get some errors when doing operations that work on lists, but not necessarily on iterators, such as `len(dict.items())` (will generate a `TypeError`).</s>

**CORRECTION**

The `dict_items` returned by calling `dict.items()` in Python 3 does indeed have a `__len__()` and will *not* generate a `TypeError`. The `dict_items` object is not a list, however, and does not have `list` methods, such as `append()`, `index()`, etc...

Also, as the other (I would say much better) answers by Hamidi and Barnes state, `dict_items` is a view object that will dynamically change when the `dict` is altered.

Comment: Nitpick: It is not technically correct that `dict.items()` etc. are iterators in Python 3: they are iterable, meaning that they can be *converted* into iterators. Reference: http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html

Comment: Major Nitpick - len(dict.items()) should be len(dictview) which is specifically given as an example in the documentation, http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items, while this answer incorrectly states that it will NOT work and will generate a type error.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: You're absolutely right. I should have checked the docs before attempting to answer.

Comment: I'm surprised that my answer, which was just plain wrong, actually received upvotes.

Comment: Very Gracious @JoelCornett

Answer (score 3):

When converting a project to python 3 using `2to3`, you can disable this by excluding the `dict` fixer for more concise output:

```
$ 2to3 -x dict *
```

Watch out for `iteritems()`, `iterkeys()` https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-dict and fix by hand.

Comment: Question is not about "how to close an eye", it was about the root cause

Comment: True, I just shared this because in retrospect I wish I knew it earlier.