# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, Using Python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, typeerror

I am getting this error while trying to clean a json data, save it into another json and finally converting it into a csv file:
**for data1 in n:  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

This is my code:

```
import json
import csv

with open('leap_data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
#print(data)
cnt=0
final_list={}

for k,v in data.items():
    for m,n in v.items():
        #print n
        cnt=cnt+1
        #print cnt
        if cnt==6:
            #print n
            for data1 in n:
                for a,b in data1.items():
                    final_list[a]=b    
                with open('output4.json', 'a') as outfile:  
                    json.dump(final_list,outfile)

            my_list = "["+open('output4.json').read().replace("}{","},{")+"]"
            data_1 = json.loads(my_list)
            print(data_1)


with open(r'samp.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
  output = csv.writer(csvfile)
  output.writerow(data_1[0].keys())
  for row in data_1:
        output.writerow(row.values())
```

Please suggest how to get rid of this

Comment: `n` is apparently an integer. Your code doesn't match the input data.

Comment: But this code is working in Python 2

Comment: You should add that information to the question. It's possible that json, or some other library, has changed between 2 and 3.

Comment: Its the same code runs fine in Python 2. Just in cases of .item() I used .iteritems() in Python 2.

Comment: You  should provide the input data also

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary's .items() doesnot return lists in Python3.
 Please refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17695456/5774004)

Sample Python2 code

```
for k, v in features.items():
```

Equivalent Python3 code

```
for k, v in list(features.items()):
```

Your code in Python3 (generated in [pythonconverter](http://www.pythonconverter.com/))

```
import json
import csv

with open('leap_data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
#print(data)
cnt=0
final_list={}

for k,v in list(data.items()):
    for m,n in list(v.items()):
        #print n
        cnt=cnt+1
        #print cnt
        if cnt==6:
            #print n
            for data1 in n:
                for a,b in list(data1.items()):
                    final_list[a]=b    
                with open('output4.json', 'a') as outfile:  
                    json.dump(final_list,outfile)

            my_list = "["+open('output4.json').read().replace("}{","},{")+"]"
            data_1 = json.loads(my_list)
            print(data_1)


with open(r'samp.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
  output = csv.writer(csvfile)
  output.writerow(list(data_1[0].keys()))
  for row in data_1:
        output.writerow(list(row.values()))
```

Hope this works!

Comment: The same error persists.
for data1 in n: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Can you share sample input json files.