# Python: How do I randomly select a value from a dictionary key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random, key-value

I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {
    "Apple": ["Green", "Healthy", "Sweet"],
    "Banana": ["Yellow", "Squishy", "Bland"],
    "Steak": ["Red", "Protein", "Savory"]
}
```

and I want to print one random value from each key, so I tried to get them into a list first:

```
import random

food = [dict.value.random.choice()]
```

but this doesn't work (no surprise, it looks excessive and confusing)

and I want to then `print` food:

```
print food
```

and just see:

```
green
squishy
savory
```

or whatever value was randomly selected.

is creating the list unnecessary? I'll keep posting attempts.

Just to clarify why this is not a duplicate: I don't want to randomly grab an item from a dictionary, I want to randomly grab an item from a each list inside a dictionary.

Comment: Don't use dict as a variable name because it is a built-in.

Comment: Right. I only used "dict" for this example, as all the key:item pairs are also fictional.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a random value in python dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-to-get-a-random-value-in-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to loop over your values :

```
>>> my_dict = {
...     "Apple": ["Green", "Healthy", "Sweet"],
...     "Banana": ["Yellow", "Squishy", "Bland"],
...     "Steak": ["Red", "Protein", "Savory"]
... }
>>> import random
>>> food=[random.choice(i) for i in my_dict.values()]
>>> food
['Savory', 'Green', 'Squishy']
```

And for print like what you want you can use `join` function or loop over `food` and print the elements one by one :

```
>>> print '\n'.join(food)
Savory
Green
Squishy
>>> for val in food :
...      print val
... 
Savory
Green
Squishy
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a for loop:

```
import random

dict = {
    "Apple": ["Green", "Healthy", "Sweet"],
    "Banana": ["Yellow", "Squishy", "Bland"],
    "Steak": ["Red", "Protein", "Savory"]
}

for key, value in dict.items():
    print random.choice(value), key
```

result:

```
Red Steak
Healthy Apple
Bland Banana
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension as in

```
import random
choices = [random.choice(v) for k, v in your_dict.items()] # iterate over the dict items
print(choices)
```

Output

```
['Protein', 'Green', 'Squishy']
```

Comment: Not my downvote but probably because your answer is exactly the same as @Kasra

Comment: It's not exactly the same and all three answer were created at nearly the same time. I don't think that a similarity is good justification.

Answer (score 1):

(BTW-Change the name 'dict' to something else)

```
# for python3
from random import randint
data = {
  "Apple": ["Green", "Healthy", "Sweet"],
  "Banana": ["Yellow", "Squishy", "Bland"],
  "Steak": ["Red", "Protein", "Savory"]
}

for  key, value in data.items():
  print(key + ":" + value[randint(0,2)])
```

**Output** (will change depending on the random int values)

```
sh-4.2# python3 main.py                                                                                                                                                         
Apple:Sweet                                                                                                                                                                     
Steak:Red                                                                                                                                                                       
Banana:Squishy
```

Amendment 01 (@ Selcuk's question)

```
for  key, value in data.items():
  length = len(value)
  print(key + ":" + value[randint(0,length-1)])
```

Comment: What happens if some of the lists are longer than others?

Comment: Right! I tend to use 'dict' in examples because of the obvious association, forgetting that "dict" is built-in.

Comment: @Selcuk- Hope this answers your question (Amendment 01 on my original answer)

Answer (score 0):

After thoroughly going through docs and using all of the very useful answers provided above, this is what I found to be the most clean and obvious:

```
import random  

food_char = {
    "Apple": ["Green", "Healthy", "Sweet"],
    "Banana": ["Yellow", "Squishy", "Bland"],
    "Steak": ["Red", "Protein", "Savory"]
}

food=[random.choice(i) for i in food_char.values()]

for item in food:
    print item
```