# How to return a the same key and value pair so that I can use this them in separate instances of my Python3 program with random.choice(list())?

Tags: python

I want to return Caracas with Venezuela and Toronto with Canada. I want to use Caracas as part of my question in a quiz I am developing, and to use Venezuela as the secret answer to that question. 
Code:

```
import random
d = {'Venezuela': 'Caracas', 'Canada': 'Toronto'}
def random_pair(x):
    print(random.choice(list(x.keys() and x.values())))
random_pair(d)
```

Returns:
Toronto
or:
Caracas
I want it to return:
Canada
Toronto
or:
Venezuela
Caracas
I even tried

```
print(random.choice(list(d.keys()))
print(random.choice(list(d.values()))
```

but that could return Caracas while returning Canada.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-to-get-a-random-value-in-python-dictionary

Comment: if you got random key then use it to get value directly from directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use `d.items()` instead of `d.keys()` and `d.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

`d.keys()` and `d.values()` are not ordered. They are each in an arbitrary order, which is why they don't match when you try to pick from a list of them.

`d.items()` gives you the key & value as a pair, together, so you can safely choose a random element.

Alternatively, you can also pick a random key `k`, and just lookup the associated value: `dict[k]` which will equal the value.