# Get A Random Value from dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

How can I get a random pair from a dict? I'm making a game on black jack so user will get a random pair from

```
deck_of_cards = {'A':11,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,'Q':10,'K':10}
```

and it will get stored in a **dictionary**

```
player_deck = {}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Remember player_deck needs to be dictionary

Comment: `player_card = []
player_card += random.choice(dict(d.items())
print player_card`

Comment: but it works in list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a random value in python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-to-get-a-random-value-in-python-dictionary)

Comment: just wanted to point out that 'A' isn't always 11 in black jack... I hope your program deals with that later on. Also, it seems superfluous to build this dict at all, where you can simply do `deck='23456789TJQKA'` choose a random character and handle values later

Comment: i too thought of this but later assigning values will be too much of if and else so i thought why not use dictionary

Comment: yeah A's value depend on player @OferSadan i am thinking that after it goes greater than 21 i will replace the value of A with 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear how you want to simulate a deck with this dict.

If you just use `random.choice` multiple times, you might get the same card twice, which probably shouldn't happen.

You could create a whole deck (as a list, not as a dict), [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) it, draw a card (thus removing it from the deck), and check its value.
Defining a new `Card` class isn't too hard with `namedtuple`, and it will make it easier to work with afterwards (Thanks to @MaartenFabré for the comment):

```
# encoding: utf-8
import random
from collections import namedtuple


class Card(namedtuple('Card', ['face', 'color'])):
    colors = ['♠', '♥', '♦', '♣']
    faces = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
    values = dict(zip(faces, [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.face + self.color

    def value(self):
        return Card.values[self.face]

    @staticmethod
    def all():
        return [Card(face, color)
                for color in Card.colors for face in Card.faces]

deck = Card.all()

print(deck)
# ['A♠', '2♠', '3♠', '4♠', '5♠', '6♠', '7♠', '8♠', '9♠', '10♠', 'J♠', 'Q♠', 'K♠', 'A♥', '2♥', '3♥', '4♥', '5♥', '6♥', '7♥', '8♥', '9♥', '10♥', 'J♥', 'Q♥', 'K♥', 'A♦', '2♦', '3♦', '4♦', '5♦', '6♦', '7♦', '8♦', '9♦', '10♦', 'J♦', 'Q♦', 'K♦', 'A♣', '2♣', '3♣', '4♣', '5♣', '6♣', '7♣', '8♣', '9♣', '10♣', 'J♣', 'Q♣', 'K♣']

random.shuffle(deck)

print(deck)
# ['9♣', '4♠', 'J♥', '9♦', '10♠', 'K♣', '8♥', '3♣', 'J♣', '10♦', '8♦', 'A♣', '7♦', '3♠', '7♠', 'Q♣', '7♥', 'Q♦', 'A♦', '9♥', '2♠', '7♣', '6♦', '4♣', 'Q♠', '3♥', 'K♠', '6♣', '5♦', '4♥', '5♣', '2♣', '2♥', '6♥', '8♠', '2♦', '4♦', '8♣', 'K♦', '10♥', 'K♥', '5♠', 'J♦', '5♥', 'A♥', '9♠', '6♠', 'Q♥', '10♣', 'A♠', '3♦', 'J♠']

a_card = deck.pop()
print(a_card)
# J♠
print(a_card.face)
# J
print(a_card.color)
# ♠
print(a_card.value())
# 10
```

Comment: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: on line `values = dict(zip(faces, [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]))`

Comment: @mvrht: Yes, I use a different data type than in your question. A deck shouldn't be a `dict` in my humble opinion.

Comment: what should it be ?

Comment: @mvrht: A deck could be a list with 52 cards. You can shuffle the list and draw the first card, just like you would with a deck. You can keep a dict to get the values for each card.

Comment: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-e81d0898e49d> in <module>()
      1 colors = ['spades', 'hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs']

      2 faces = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']

----> 3 values = dict(zip(faces, [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]))

      4 deck = [face + ' of ' + color for color in colors for face in faces]

      5 


TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
`

Comment: @mvrht: Ahhhhh. Did you overwrite the function `dict()` with a variable called `dict`? That's one of the reasons you shouldn't do so ;)

Comment: Could you explain in detail this line
`values = dict(zip(faces, [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]))`

Comment: and this line 
`color for color in colors for face in faces`

Comment: @mvrht: We have a list with 13 elements and a list with 4 elements. The double list comprehension creates a list with 52 elements, where every element from one list has been mixed with every element from the other list. It's equivalent to two nested for loops.

Comment: `dict(zip(faces, [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]))` just recreates your dict from a list of keys and a list of values.

Comment: Thanks Buddy !  You are life saver

Comment: Instead of `deck = [face + ' of ' + color for color in colors for face in faces]` I would do `deck = list(itertools.product(colors, faces))` to get a list of tuples. How you represent them 'x of y' or another way can be done on another level, but this way you can later check the color or face easier. A separate class (or `namedTuple`) might be easier even

Comment: @MaartenFabré: I tried to integerate your comment. Any suggestion for improvement is welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Use `random.choice()`

```
import random
player_deck = {}
deck_of_cards = {'A':11,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,'Q':10,'K':10}

key, value = random.choice(list(deck_of_cards.items()))
player_deck[key] = value
```

Or in case you want key and value directly into a dictionary, you can do it like this

```
player_deck = dict([random.choice(list(deck_of_cards.items()))])
```

Comment: it does not store it in dictionary

Comment: @mvrht Just add the key and value to your dictionary

Comment: just `dict([random.choice(list(deck_of_cards.items())])` should create a dict

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: SyntaxError, one `)` is missing. There's no way OP's data structure helps with Blackjack, though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, I updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Use `random.choice`

```
import random
player_deck = {}
deck_of_cards = {'A':11,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,'Q':10,'K':10}
d = random.choice(list(deck_of_cards.items()))
player_deck.update(d)
print(player_deck)
{'9': 9}
```

Comment: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import random

deck_of_cards = {'A':11,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,'Q':10,'K':10}
player_deck = dict(random.sample(deck_of_cards.items(),1))
```

where I am basically asking for '1' random sample from the dictionary and typecasting the output to a dictionary (as it returns a list).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choice`:

```
import random
player_deck=[]
player_deck.append(random.choice(list(deck_of_cards.items())))
print(player_deck)
```