# Random Max Key in dictionary in case of tie

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `dictionary`: keys are strings, values are float.

Example:

```
A = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':2, 'd':0}
```

I'd like to get `'b'` or `'c'` as answer with equal probability. I found a way to get said behaviour. However I'm not convinced this is best practice.

```
import random

A = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':2, 'd':0}
all = (A.items())
values = [(x[1],random.random(),x[0]) for x in all]
maxIndex = values.index(max(values))
print(values[maxIndex][2])
```

Is there a better (or even more elegant) approach?

Comment: `random.choice(d.keys())` answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-to-get-a-random-value-in-python-dictionary)

Comment: @Lex this doesn't look like the same thing. It's like, first find the maximum value, and then choose a random key that maps to that value.

Comment: @Jedi `A` is in this form. I'm not worried about O(n) as n=4 in this case. I'd be great to see a faster approach in general though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random
A = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':2, 'd':0}

mv = max(A.values())
random.choice([k for (k, v) in A.items() if v == mv])
=> 'b' # or 'c'
```

First, we find the maximum value and then we randomly pick one of the keys that match that value. We're using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice), which guarantees a random selection with uniform distribution.