# How to randomly select an item from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I'm a python beginner trying to make a game of blackjack, and have been continuously getting multiple keyerrors regarding this code

```
def rank(rank):
    rank={
        '2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'Jack':10,
       'King':10,'Queen':10,'Ace':1}
    return random.choice(rank)
```

The error occurs when I try calling the function like this

```
def draw_card(card):
    card_rank=Card.rank(rank)
    card_suit=Card.suit(suit)
    card={card_suit:card_rank}
    return card
```

to try and use the 'rank' function in class 'Card' to apply attributes to a new 'card' variable

Comment: Why are you calling `random.choice` on a dict, and why is everything in the `rank` function named `rank`?

Comment: You should make a `Card` class, instantiate 52 `Card` objects in a list, and then [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a random value in python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-to-get-a-random-value-in-python-dictionary)

Comment: Is this the exact code you are trying to run? Because it's full of syntactical and logical errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`random.choice` takes a `list` (or `tuple`) in input (it needs integer-indexable objects).

So just convert `rank` dictionary (the values, it is) to a `list` then pick a value: like this (I've created a new function because the `rank(rank)` bit made no sense, you don't need a parameter to pick a card:

```
# globally defined (constant), pointless to define it locally, you may
# need it in another part of the program
rank={'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'Jack':10,
   'King':10,'Queen':10,'Ace':1}

def pick():       
    return random.choice(list(rank.values()))
```

`list(rank.values())` is *required* in python 3, dictionary values are no longer of `list` type. Maybe you want to pre-compute this list to save computation time.

Comment: Even with the `list` call, the fact that a dict is involved at all is pointless, and generating new random cards on demand is probably inappropriate in the first place.

Comment: yep, but the dict may be used somewhere else, I made it global

Comment: Thank you, this has been helpful. I do need the rank as a dictionary, though, so that I can return to the user the rank+suit of their card (e.g. "Ace of Spades") and keep the blackjack value of each card assigned to it's name.