# How to get a random element from a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I want to get a value `"element":"value"` from a dictionary in python.

```py
import random

country = {
"Spain":"Madrid",
"UK":"London",
"France":"Paris"
} 

random.choice(country)
```

It returns me the following :

```sh
File "C:\Users\${username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\random.py", line 262, in choice
    return seq[i]
KeyError: 10
```

My aim, is to select a random value and be left with 1 Country - City left in the dictionary.
This does not answer my question : [How to get a random value from dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-to-get-a-random-value-from-dictionary-in-python/32865250#32865250)

Comment: Use the solution in the duplicate to get random key. It's value is `country[key]`. So `{key: country[key]}` is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `items` method to get the pairs, then transform it to a list that supports indexing: 
`random.choice(list(country.items()))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You solved my problem mate

Answer (score 0):

i think you can implement in following way

```
import random

country = {
"Spain":"Madrid",
"UK":"London",
"France":"Paris"
}
keys = list(country.keys())
random_key = keys[random.randint(0, len(keys)-1)]
print(country[random_key])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `random.choice` from the `keys()` of the `dict` for instance.

You could print the values or make a new `dict` with just that entry:

```
import random

country = {
"Spain":"Madrid",
"UK":"London",
"France":"Paris"
}

k = random.choice(list(country.keys()))
print(k, country[k])
print({k:country[k]})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no order in a dictionary. The only list can be used for `random.sample`.

So change your code to `random.choice(list(country.items()))`