# Randomly choosing variable out of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, random

I'm trying to have python choose a random variable out of my dictionary to run in the code but can't seem to get the correct syntax for it. If anyone can help that would be great.

```
def battle():
    moveset_dict = {
    "1": 25, 
    "2": 50,
    "3": 75,
    "4": 100,
    }
    hp = 100

    while hp > 0 :
        attack_chosen =  random.range(len(moveset_dict))
        hp = hp - attack_chosen
        print("Alar used", attack_chosen, "Valor has", hp, "hp")

    else:
        print("Valor has fainted")

battle()
```

Comment: Try `random.choice(moveset_dict.keys())`

Comment: @dcg: `random.choice(list(moveset_dict))`, because `choice` requires a sequence, and `.keys()` returns an iterator. (Also, OP, you presumably want `hp -= moveset_dict[attack_chosen]`)

Comment: @Amadan You're rigth.

Comment: I get TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Comment: See @Amadan comment

Comment: This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-to-get-a-random-value-from-dictionary-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You should Try

```
import random
def battle():
    moveset_dict = {
    "1": 25, 
    "2": 50,
    "3": 75,
    "4": 100,
    }
    hp = 100

    while hp > 0 :
        attack_chosen =  random.choice(range(len(moveset_dict)))
        hp = hp - attack_chosen
        print("Alar used", attack_chosen, "Valor has", hp, "hp")

    else:
        print("Valor has fainted")

battle()
```