# Select a random key from 2 Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries in Python
the user is asked to press a key to show a random key from the 2 dictionaries
How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a random value from dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-to-get-a-random-value-from-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use random.choice:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice([*dict1.keys(), *dict2.keys()])
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried it and it does not select a key from one of the two dictionaries, but it selects one a random hall disctionary