# Is there anyway to put numbers in a dictionary and randomly pick them and complete random math problems in python?

Tags: python

I was wondering if this was possible cause I want to try and make a random number generator by just adding numbers that are stored in a dictionary, is this possible? Also, is it possible to store the numbers in a .json file and randomly pick the numbers for random addition problems?

If possible, I want the ouput to output the answers to 10 random math questions, which I believe can be done with a for i in range(10) loop. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: [How to get a random value from dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4859292)

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly.