# How to get random item and random value from dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a random value from one of the ice-cream flavors. I've tried using random, pop items, but they all print out the entire line. While I'm trying to just get one of the values (cone flavors) and a flavor.

```
dict = {
    "vanilla": ["vanilla-cone", "chocolate-cone","cookie-dough-cone", "mint-cone", "rainbow-cone"],
    "Chocolate": ["vanilla-cone", "chocolate-cone","cookie-dough-cone", "mint-cone", "rainbow-cone"],
    "Cookie-dough": ["vanilla-cone", "chocolate-cone","cookie-dough-cone", "mint-cone", "rainbow-cone"],
    "Mint-Chocolate": ["vanilla-cone", "chocolate-cone","cookie-dough-cone", "mint-cone", "rainbow-cone"],
    "Rainbow": ["vanilla-cone", "chocolate-cone","cookie-dough-cone", "mint-cone", "rainbow-cone"]
}

print (dict.popitem())
or 
print(random.choice(list(dict.items())))
```

```
Expected Output:
{"Mint-Chocolate": "vanilla-cone"}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to get as output? you have a dict with lists as values. Do you want a random list, or a random item from a random list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a random value from dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-to-get-a-random-value-from-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: Can you share an expectd output ?

Comment: An expected outpout would be:

Comment: {"Rainbow": "Vanilla-Cone"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code after your code:

```
flavor = random.choice(list(dict))
seq = ["vanilla-cone", "chocolate-cone","cookie-dough-cone", 
"mint-cone", "rainbow-cone"]
cone = random.choice(seq)
print(flavor, ":", cone)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because `dict.items` return pairs of key value tuple, if you want spesific flavor you need to choose a key and than choose again from your list of flavor for spesific flavor
try this code

```
print(random.choice(dict[random.choice(list(dict.keys()))]))
```

also you can choose directly from the values like this

```
print(random.choice(random.choice(list(dict.values()))))
```

Comment: Gotcha and is it possible to print out the flavor as well as the cone?

Comment: yes, you need to choose the flavor and store it in variable, than ramdom a cone and after those 2 steps print them together.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in 2 steps, first get a key, then a value. Also don't name it `dict`, that the dictionnary constructor keyword

```
import random

# pick a random key
rand_key = random.choice(list(values))
# pick a random value between the values given by the key
rand_value = random.choice(values[rand_key])

print(rand_key, rand_value)
```

Here some results after some run

```
Rainbow cookie-dough-cone
Mint-Chocolate chocolate-cone
Cookie-dough chocolate-cone
```

---

To get a `dict` output,

- use dict literal instanciation

  ```
  rand_key = random.choice(list(values))
  result = {rand_key: random.choice(values[rand_key])}
   # {'Chocolate': 'chocolate-cone'}
  ```
- or a dict-comprehension

  ```
  result = {k: random.sample(values[k], 1)[0] for k in random.sample(list(values), 1)}
  ```

Comment: Is there a possibility to use the dict constructor keyword directly? Like the list keyword

Comment: @AnlactHuynh Why so ? To get your expected output do `result = {rand_key: random.choice(values[rand_key])}`

Comment: Nothing particular, I felt that it can be used faster? Also, the string of code you just sent returned
    ```result = {rand_key: random.choice(values[rand_key])}
NameError: name 'rand_key' is not defined```

Comment: @AnlactHuynh  `rand_key` was defined in the previous code. You can think about accepting the answer if it satisfies you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of dictionary is wrong, because if I understand correctly you want to create a random ice cream with random flavor and random cone.

This is an example of this scenario using just a list and `random.choice` two times.

```
import random

flavors = ['vanilla', 'chocolate', 'cookie-dough', 'mint-chocolate', 'rainbow']

cone = random.choice(flavors) + '-cone'
icecream = random.choice(flavors)
```