# popitem () method in Python 3.10 does not work as it worked in Python 3.7

Tags: dictionary, random, python-3.10, lifo

In Python 3.7 **popitem ()** method return and remove **random** pair key-values.
But in Python 3.10 popitem () return and remove **LIFO** pair key-values.
What can i use instead popitem () in Python 3.10 for return and remove **random** pair in dictionary?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean Python 3.5 rather than Python 3.7? In Python 3.7, dicts retain their insertion order, just like in Python 3.10. In Python 3.5, what `popitem` returns is based on the internal hash table, making it a bit unpredictable, but it's not really "random".

Comment: @MarkDickinson 
Thanks! But question reamained) What dictionary method should i use instead **popitem**? For example, it is necessary in imitation for card games.

Comment: Would something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-to-get-a-random-value-from-dictionary help?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes! Thanks! but this way more code is needed)