# Setting a random value from a list in Python

Tags: python, locust

Basic question, but how do I pick random values from this list:

```
TS_IDs = {
'69397': 30,
'10259': 30,
'87104': 30
}
```

Using this function:

```
def set_ts_id_random():
ts_id_random = <here I want to pick a random value>
print("random_ts_id:", ts_id_random)
return ts_id_random
```

Comment: First of all that's not a list, it's a dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a random key-value pair from a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-can-i-get-a-random-key-value-pair-from-a-dictionary)

Comment: Yes, so I get this error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'tuple'. It seems the values being printed is this: random_ts_id: ('10271', 30). How do I get jst the values from the first collum in my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `random.choice` to choose a value from the dictionary's value:**

```
import random

TS_IDs = {
'69397': 30,
'10259': 30,
'87104': 30
}

def set_ts_id_random():
    ts_id_random = random.choice(list(TS_IDs.values()))
    print("random_ts_id:", ts_id_random)
    return ts_id_random

set_ts_id_random()
```

Output:

```
random_ts_id: 30
```

Remember, `TS_IDs` is a `dict`, not a `list`. It consist of key/value pairs. My code returns a random value, but if you'd rather have a random key, change `ts_id_random = random.choice(list(TS_IDs.values()))` to `ts_id_random = random.choice(list(TS_IDs.keys()))`.

Comment: Great that you answered, but such questions shouldnt be entertained when answers to such questions are already answered previously.