Keyerror: 0 in Python 3.12
I'm new to python and I'm programming the Blackjack game in python with a friend of mine. I'm getting Keyerror:0 on this lines:
card1=random.choice(cards)
card2=random.choice(cards)
Is it a writing mistake or something bigger? Please help me
For context, here's the part of the code with those lines:
import random
nplayers=int(input(f"Insert the number of players: "))
pplayers=1
cards={
    1: "A",
    2: "2",
    3: "3",
    4: "4",
    5: "5",
    6: "6",
    7: "7",
    8: "8",
    9: "9",
    10: ["10", "J", "Q", "K"],
    11: "A"
}
card1=random.choice(cards)
card2=random.choice(cards)
def give_cards():
    print(f"Player {pplayers} cards are: " + str(card1) +"; " + str(card2))
while pplayers<=nplayers:
    give_cards()
    pplayers+=1
    card1=random.choice(cards)
    card2=random.choice(cards)```




What output are you expecting? For example, a 10 value would give multiple cards? Here's a post about getting random elements of a dict https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-can-i-get-a-random-key-value-pair-from-a-dictionary#4859322

@OneCricketeer but why getting the error as dict has  no 0 element

"Is it a writing mistake[...]?" yes. Per the documentation of choice: "Return a random element from [a] non-empty sequence" A dict is not a sequence.

@sahasrara62 because it works on sequences (sequential indexed collections), so what it does is get a random index between 0 (include) and len(input) (excluded), then it returns the value at that index. OP's dict is of length 11, so it'll randomly pick an index from 0 to 10 (included), if it gets 0 they get an error because that key doesn't exist. And it'll never return "A".

The random.choice() function expects a sequence (like a list) and you are providing a dictionary. This is why you are getting a KeyError.
To fix this, you need to convert the dictionary values to a list. Here’s how you can do it:
#converts dictionary to list
# it will become [(1, 'A'),....(10, ['10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'])..]
cards_list = list(cards.items())

card1=random.choice(cards_list)
card2=random.choice(cards_list)


A dictionary is not a sequence.
Try to get the keys or values:
card1=random.choice(cards.keys())

or
card2=random.choice(cards.values())

And then you should think of what you do when it gets the 10 value (the list)

list(card.keys()) or list(card.values()) you need to provide sequence to the random.choice

Neither keys nor values have been sequences since Python 3. key views are sets, and value views are pretty much just (reversible) iterables.

This wouldn't be correct either, both due to one of the values being a list, and due to resulting in incorrect probabilities. The sequence should have 13 (or 52) elements.

@interjay that is true, the picker would need to use a weighted RNG (using random.choices) as well, or more simply not use a dict at all as there's no reason to I can think of. Not only that, but normal RNGs have no memory which definitely does not simulate a deck of cards and its dealing, instead most likely the deck should be generated, shuffled, then cards should be popped off the top to be "dealt". Here technically nothing prevents every card draw to be the same.
