# How to urlencode a querystring in Python?

Tags: python, urllib, urlencode

I am trying to urlencode this string before I submit.

```
queryString = 'eventName=' + evt.fields["eventName"] + '&' + 'eventDescription=' + evt.fields["eventDescription"];
```

Answer (score 729, accepted):

You need to pass your parameters into [`urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) as either a mapping (dict), or a sequence of 2-tuples, like:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> f = { 'eventName' : 'myEvent', 'eventDescription' : 'cool event'}
>>> urllib.urlencode(f)
'eventName=myEvent&eventDescription=cool+event'
```

**Python 3 or above**

Use [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode):

```
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode(f)
eventName=myEvent&eventDescription=cool+event
```

Note that this does *not* do url encoding in the commonly used sense (look at the output). For that use [`urllib.parse.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus).

Comment: I was just about to put solved I came up w/ the same solution. Thanks.

Comment: "Note that the urllib.urlencode does not always do the trick. The problem is that some services care about the order of arguments, which gets lost when you create the dictionary. For such cases, urllib.quote_plus is better, as Ricky suggested."

Comment: Technically, that's a bug in the services, isn't it?

Comment: and how would one do this if you just want to make a string URL safe, without building a full query argument string?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082314/how-to-convert-a-url-string-to-safe-characters-with-python or Ricky's answer to this question.

Comment: You can pass a list of tuples to urlencode and order is preserved: `urllib.urlencode([('name', 'brandon'), ('x', 1000)])` produces `'name=brandon&x=1000'`  (as the answer states, though it does not provide example code for it)

Comment: @bk0 it seems your method is only valid for dictionaries, and not strings.

Comment: @Blairg23 Unless the same keys are repeated multiple times, wouldn't it work to just pass it an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: @JohnStrood - Python 2.7 and earlier have `urlparse`, 3.0+ uses `urllib.parse`

Comment: @holdenweb for signatures and other crypto stuff order is important

Comment: In which case why not just work with the original query string, rather than its decomposition by the parser, which is available to allow easy access to individual parameter values.

Comment: note that dictionaries are officially sorted as of python 3.7+ (and cpython 3.6+)

Comment: urllib has been split up in Python 3.

The urllib.urlencode() function is now urllib.parse.urlencode()

Comment: @holdenweb for escaping you have to not escape the meta parts of the URL, the & being the most important one.    For simple alphanumeric strings, what you suggest is fine.

Answer (score 1309):

## Python 2

What you're looking for is [`urllib.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus):

```
safe_string = urllib.quote_plus('string_of_characters_like_these:$#@=?%^Q^$')

#Value: 'string_of_characters_like_these%3A%24%23%40%3D%3F%25%5EQ%5E%24'
```

## Python 3

In Python 3, the `urllib` package has been broken into smaller components. You'll use [`urllib.parse.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) (note the `parse` child module)

```
import urllib.parse
safe_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case however I need to put: `import urllib.parse ... urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)`

Comment: very good,but why does not used to Unicode?if the url string is Unicode,I must encode it to UTF-8.Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: This works great, but I couldn't access some online services (REST) until I added this parameter   safe=';/?:@&=+$,'

Comment: I tried that in Python 3 but was not able to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557606/how-to-url-encode-in-python-3

Comment: `python3 -c "import urllib.parse, sys; print(urllib.parse.quote_plus(sys.argv[1])) "string to encode"` for a one liner on the command line

Comment: This one (the Python 3 version) solved it for me for a telegram bot sending a message with accents and spaces to a channel.

Comment: @AmosJoshua I think you missed a double quote `"` just after the double round closing brackets `))`, it should be:

`python3 -c "import urllib.parse, sys; print(urllib.parse.quote_plus(sys.argv[1]))" "string to encode"`

Comment: @lgespee - good point, thanks for pointing that out. I can't seem to be able to edit the comment... I hope yours will rise further up

Comment: You can use `urllib.parse.quote` if you want spaces to be encoded as `%20` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 99):

Try [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of urllib and you don't need to bother with urlencode!

```
import requests
requests.get('http://youraddress.com', params=evt.fields)
```

**EDIT:**

If you need **ordered name-value pairs** or multiple values for a name then set params like so:

```
params=[('name1','value11'), ('name1','value12'), ('name2','value21'), ...]
```

instead of using a dictionary.

Comment: This does not address the issue of ordering the name value pairs, also this requires the permission to install external libraries which might not be doable for the project.

Comment: I posted the minimal code that would work for the OP. The OP did not request ordered pairs however it is also doable, see my update.

Comment: @dreftymac: this does address ordering (although it was not part of the question), please read my updated answer.

Answer (score 41):

#### Context

- Python (version 2.7.2 )

#### Problem

- You want to generate a urlencoded query string.
- You have a dictionary or object containing the name-value pairs.
- You want to be able to control the output ordering of the name-value pairs.

#### Solution

- urllib.urlencode
- urllib.quote_plus

#### Pitfalls

- dictionary output arbitrary ordering of name-value pairs

  - (see also: [Why is python ordering my dictionary like so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526125))
  - (see also: [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928))
- handling cases when you *DO NOT* care about the ordering of the name-value pairs
- handling cases when you *DO* care about the ordering of the name-value pairs
- handling cases where a single name needs to appear more than once in the set of all name-value pairs

#### Example

The following is a complete solution, including how to deal with some pitfalls.

```
### ********************
## init python (version 2.7.2 )
import urllib

### ********************
## first setup a dictionary of name-value pairs
dict_name_value_pairs = {
  "bravo"   : "True != False",
  "alpha"   : "http://www.example.com",
  "charlie" : "hello world",
  "delta"   : "1234567 !@#$%^&*",
  "echo"    : "user@example.com",
  }

### ********************
## setup an exact ordering for the name-value pairs
ary_ordered_names = []
ary_ordered_names.append('alpha')
ary_ordered_names.append('bravo')
ary_ordered_names.append('charlie')
ary_ordered_names.append('delta')
ary_ordered_names.append('echo')

### ********************
## show the output results
if('NO we DO NOT care about the ordering of name-value pairs'):
  queryString  = urllib.urlencode(dict_name_value_pairs)
  print queryString 
  """
  echo=user%40example.com&bravo=True+%21%3D+False&delta=1234567+%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2A&charlie=hello+world&alpha=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com
  """

if('YES we DO care about the ordering of name-value pairs'):
  queryString  = "&".join( [ item+'='+urllib.quote_plus(dict_name_value_pairs[item]) for item in ary_ordered_names ] )
  print queryString
  """
  alpha=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&bravo=True+%21%3D+False&charlie=hello+world&delta=1234567+%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2A&echo=user%40example.com
  """
```

Answer (score 37):

Python 3:

[`urllib.parse.quote_plus(string, safe='', encoding=None, errors=None)`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urllib#urllib.parse.quote_plus)

Comment: I prefer `urllib.parse.quote()` myself since it uses `%20` rather than `+`.

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
urllib.pathname2url(stringToURLEncode)
```

`urlencode` won't work because it only works on dictionaries. `quote_plus` didn't produce the correct output.

Comment: That's really helpful! In my case, I only have a portion of string that I want to URL-encode, for example I want to transform `my string` to `my%20string`. Your solution works like a charm for that!

Comment: Worked for me to get `%20` instead of `+`. Thanks

Comment: In Python 3. It is now `urllib.request.pathname2url`

Answer (score 22):

Note that the urllib.urlencode does not always do the trick. The problem is that some services care about the order of arguments, which gets lost when you create the dictionary. For such cases, urllib.quote_plus is better, as Ricky suggested.

Comment: It works fine and preserves order if you pass a list of tuples: `>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlencode([('name', 'brandon'), ('uid', 1000)])
'name=brandon&uid=1000'
`

Answer (score 15):

In Python 3, this worked with me

```py
import urllib

urllib.parse.quote(query)
```

Comment: It worked for me to encode a string as part of the whole url

Comment: I had to do `import urllib.parse`, otherwise I get "AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'parse'".

Answer (score 9):

```
import urllib.parse
query = 'Hellö Wörld@Python'
urllib.parse.quote(query) # returns Hell%C3%B6%20W%C3%B6rld%40Python
```

Comment: `urllib.parse.quote` is already mentioned in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266288/2745495).

Comment: @GinoMempin The problem with the other answer is that says `import urllib` when it should be `urllib.parse`. Yes, they could also have suggested an edit, but as it is now, this answer is the most correct of the two.

Answer (score 6):

for future references (ex: for python3)

```
>>> import urllib.request as req
>>> query = 'eventName=theEvent&eventDescription=testDesc'
>>> req.pathname2url(query)
>>> 'eventName%3DtheEvent%26eventDescription%3DtestDesc'
```

Comment: usually you only want to url encode the values, what you have done here would make an invalid GET query

Comment: The output for `'c:/2 < 3'` on Windows is `'///C://2%20%3C%203'`. I want something that would just output `'c:/2%20%3C%203'`.

Answer (score 6):

For use in scripts/programs which need to support both python 2 and 3, the six module provides quote and urlencode functions:

```
>>> from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlencode, quote
>>> data = {'some': 'query', 'for': 'encoding'}
>>> urlencode(data)
'some=query&for=encoding'
>>> url = '/some/url/with spaces and %;!<>&'
>>> quote(url)
'/some/url/with%20spaces%20and%20%25%3B%21%3C%3E%26'
```

Answer (score 5):

#### If the urllib.parse.urlencode( ) is giving you errors , then Try the urllib3 module .

The **syntax** is as follows :

```
import urllib3
urllib3.request.urlencode({"user" : "john" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that might not have been mentioned already is that `urllib.urlencode()` will encode empty values in the dictionary as the string `None` instead of having that parameter as absent. I don't know if this is typically desired or not, but does not fit my use case, hence I have to use `quote_plus`.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3 **urllib3** works properly, you can use as follow as per its [*official docs*](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#making-requests) :

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request(
     'GET',
     'https://api.prylabs.net/eth/v1alpha1/beacon/attestations',
     fields={  # here fields are the query params
          'epoch': 1234,
          'pageSize': pageSize 
      } 
 )
response = attestations.data.decode('UTF-8')
```

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to use urllib.

https://github.com/wayne931121/Python_URL_Decode

```py
URL_RFC_3986 = {
"!": "%21", "#": "%23", "$": "%24", "&": "%26", "'": "%27", "(": "%28", ")": "%29", "*": "%2A", "+": "%2B", 
",": "%2C", "/": "%2F", ":": "%3A", ";": "%3B", "=": "%3D", "?": "%3F", "@": "%40", "[": "%5B", "]": "%5D",
}

def url_encoder(b):
    # https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%99%BE%E5%88%86%E5%8F%B7%E7%BC%96%E7%A0%81
    if type(b)==bytes:
        b = b.decode(encoding="utf-8") #byte can't insert many utf8 charaters
    result = bytearray() #bytearray: rw, bytes: read-only
    for i in b:
        if i in URL_RFC_3986:
            for j in URL_RFC_3986[i]:
                result.append(ord(j))
            continue
        i = bytes(i, encoding="utf-8")
        if len(i)==1:
            result.append(ord(i))
        else:
            for c in i:
                c = hex(c)[2:].upper()
                result.append(ord("%"))
                result.append(ord(c[0:1]))
                result.append(ord(c[1:2]))
    result = result.decode(encoding="ascii")
    return result

#print(url_encoder("我好棒==%%0.0:)")) ==> '%E6%88%91%E5%A5%BD%E6%A3%92%3D%3D%%0.0%3A%29'
```