# How to convert a dictionary to query string in Python?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

After using `cgi.parse_qs()`, how to convert the result (dictionary) back to query string? Looking for something similar to  `urllib.urlencode()`.

Comment: N.B: [`cgi.parse_qs()` is deprecated. Use urlparse.parse_qs() instead.](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_qs)

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python

Answer (score 216, accepted):

### Python 3

> `urllib.parse.urlencode(query, doseq=False, [...])`

> Convert **a mapping object** or a sequence of two-element tuples, which may contain str or bytes objects, to a percent-encoded ASCII text string.

> — [Python 3 `urllib.parse` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)

A `dict` is a mapping.

### Legacy Python

> `urllib.urlencode`(`query`[, `doseq`])
> Convert **a mapping object** or a sequence of two-element tuples to a “percent-encoded” string... a series of `key=value` pairs separated by `'&'` characters...

> — [Python 2.7 `urllib` docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)

Comment: This is true, but the `dict` returned by `cgi.parse_qs()` actually has `list`s as its "values". Passing these straight in will result in very odd looking query strings.

Comment: True enough. That'll teach me to read more than the first sentence!

Comment: [urllib.parse.urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) in Python 3.

Comment: The problem is that urlencode will convert space into +, which is not recommended.

Comment: @user1633272: Not recommended according to who?

Comment: is there a way that I can use `urlencode()` just to make use of `doseq` param. i.e. I do not want any of the characters to be encoded. I know there is a `safe` param, but that would require me to list out each character. I am looking for a wild-card character for `safe` param so that it understands that it has to encode nothing.

Comment: Based on my findings, I do not think anything like such^ exists. And thus, I am exploring the option to first let it get encode and then decode. I know its a round-trip, but I couldn't think of any other alternative except writing the logic of `doseq` on my own in my codebase.

Comment: I realised I can achieve this^^ by passing my own `quote_via` function. Something like: `urlencode(params, doseq=True, quote_via=lambda a, b, c, d : a)`

Comment: Instead of `unquote_plus(urlencode(params, doseq=True))`

Answer (score 108):

In python3, slightly different:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
urlencode({'pram1': 'foo', 'param2': 'bar'})
```

output: `'pram1=foo&param2=bar'`

for python2 and python3 compatibility, try this:

```
try:
    #python2
    from urllib import urlencode
except ImportError:
    #python3
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
```

Answer (score 12):

You're looking for something *exactly* like `urllib.urlencode()`!

However, when you call [`parse_qs()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) (distinct from [`parse_qsl()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl)), the dictionary keys are the unique query variable names and the values are *lists of values* for each name.

In order to pass this information into [`urllib.urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode), you must "flatten" these lists. Here is how you can do it with a list comprehenshion of tuples:

```
query_pairs = [(k,v) for k,vlist in d.iteritems() for v in vlist]
urllib.urlencode(query_pairs)
```

Comment: Or you could pass `doseq=True`.

Comment: @downvoter: How could I improve this answer? It has been six years since I wrote it!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
def dictToQuery(d):
  query = ''
  for key in d.keys():
    query += str(key) + '=' + str(d[key]) + "&"
  return query
```

It takes a dictionary and convert it to a query string, just like urlencode. It'll append a final "&" to the query string, but `return query[:-1]` fixes that, if it's an issue.

Comment: Have you met `str.join()` yet? How about `urllib.quote_plus()`?

Comment: @garbados Your solution should work in simple cases. However, have a look `urlencode` in `urllib.py` (it should by in your Python install) to see why creating a query string is sometimes not quite as simple as your answer implies (in particular the need to 'quote' certain characters that aren't valid in a URL). @Ignacio has also referenced two functions that would clean up your implementation and make it correct.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Sorry for the cruddy implementation. Goes to show I should be more careful answering questions I've never faced myself.

Comment: While this may not be the best answer, it is exactly what I wanted to see when I clicked on this question's title.  I have only 4 items in a dict that I need to turn into a name=value pair separated by an '&'.  My values are controlled.  The str.join() is handy in my case but I have no need for quote_plus(), again, because it's not public-facing code :)  Thanks!

Comment: @harperville but the more correct way (`from urllib.parse import urlencode; urlencode(your_dict)`) is shorter and easier than this! I'll grant that it's sometimes smart to reinvent the wheel, even shoddily, when it's expensive or inconvenient to access existing, well-designed wheels, but here using the off-the-shelf wheel is easier and quicker than rolling your own inferior one.