# How to convert a url string to safe characters with python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following string:

```
"http://earth.google.com/gallery/kmz/women_for_women.kmz?a=large"
```

Is there some function or module to be able to convert a string like the above to a string below where all the characters are changed to be compliant with a url:

```
"http%3A%2F%2Fearth.google.com%2Fgallery%2Fkmz%2Fwomen_for_women.kmz%3Fa%3Dlarge"
```

What is the best way to do this in python?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Python 2's [urllib.quote_plus](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus), and Python 3's [urllib.parse.quote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus)

```
url = "http://earth.google.com/gallery/kmz/women_for_women.kmz?a=large"
# Python 2
urllib.quote_plus(url)
# Python 3
urllib.parse.quote_plus(url)
```

outputs:

```
'http%3A%2F%2Fearth.google.com%2Fgallery%2Fkmz%2Fwomen_for_women.kmz%3Fa%3Dlarge'
```

Comment: I think there's an issue when you want to have a space become `%2C` and it gets converted to a `+` instead.

Comment: Also, as an update, you need to use `urllib.parse.quote_plus` in Python 3

Comment: @MaxCandocia Yes, that's the job of `quote_plus`, it converts spaces to `+`, hence the name. The docs talk about the difference... `quote` is for URL path components, and `quote_plus` is for query string parameter names and values.

Answer (score 10):

Available in the Windows platform

```
#! python3.6
from urllib.parse import quote


# result: http://www.oschina.net/search?scope=bbs&q=C%E8%AF%AD%E8%A8%80
quote('http://www.oschina.net/search?scope=bbs&q=C语言',safe='/:?=&')
```

Comment: The user asked for all special characters to be converted

Comment: @DeadSec this question is over three years old at this point, but just because the OP didn't understand the code doesn't mean they shouldn't be coding. Everyone takes time to learn and you cant expect them to understand everything immediately. Have a little patience. Peace.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [urllib.quote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) or [urllib.quote_plus](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus)? Note that you do not quote the entire url string as you mentioned in the question. You normally quote the part in the path or after the query string. Whichever you are going to use in the application.

Comment: you'd quote the entire url if it were just a string that is part of a GET request.

e.g. `http://example.com/show-url-info?url=http%3A%2F%2Fearth.google.com%2Fgallery%2Fkmz%2Fwomen_for_women.kmz%3Fa%3Dlarge`

Comment: In this, the full query is part of the query.