# convert string to http string format

Tags: python, http, http-headers, special-characters

i need to make and api request and i need to convert a strin like:

```
"hello i am a special string + i contain special characters?"
```

into a request format like:

```
"hello%20i%20am%20a%20special ... ecc"
```

does python has a library to help me out?

this is my code:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("address:port")
conn.request(method="GET", url="/my/target/site?info1=this needs to be converted&info2=also this???", headers=headers)
```

thanks

Comment: Are you only trying to remove spaces?

Comment: @jon I think if there are special characters like =, >, it should also be converted

Comment: is that what you are looking for?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python

Comment: @Hedy my idea is that you do split() and then join() function for each special character that you want to endcode but ink how effecient is that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in [How to convert a url string to safe characters with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082314/how-to-convert-a-url-string-to-safe-characters-with-python)
And  [How to urlencode a querystring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python)

You can use

```py
import urllib
urllib.parse.quote_plus('string here')
```