# accessing itop database (via oql) with python urllib2

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, wget, pycurl

I am trying to access an itop database via its generic web interface. I got it working with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export http_proxy=''
SERVER=itop-test
SELECT_STATEMENT="SELECT Ticket"

wget -q -O - \
--http-user=myusername \
--http-password=$(cat /home/dummy/private/.passwd) \
"http://${SERVER}.acme.org:8000/webservices/export.php?login_mode=basic&format=csv&expression=${SELECT_STATEMENT}&fields=${FIELDS}"
```

This produces csv output as desired.
Now since the application I am building is in python, I would like to do the same in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import urllib2
import base64


select_statement = 'SELECT Ticket'
fields = ''

itop_server = 'itop-test'
username = 'myusername'
passwd_file = '/home/dummy/private/.passwd'

# extract passwd
password = open(passwd_file,'r').read().replace('\n','')
# clear http_proxy (sometimes set on ACME systems)
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# build url
url = 'http://' + itop_server + \
     '.acme.org:8000/webservices/export.php?login_mode=basic&format=csv&expression='\
     + select_statement + '&fields=' + fields
request = urllib2.Request(url)
base64string = base64.standard_b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()

print result
```

However, the python version is not working, the result contains, among other things

```
<p>Error the query can not be executed.</p>
<p>Unexpected token End of Input, found &#039;0&#039; in: <b>S</b>ELECT</p>
```

I have checked that the urls used are identical, so I guessed there must be a difference in the http header that is send(?).

Here is some output from `tcpdump -s 1024 -l -A dst itop-test.acme.org`

First wget:

```
..........@..#..2\.P.9..t..GET
/webservices/export.php?login_mode=basic&format=csv&expression=SELECT%20Ticket&fields= HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */* 
Host: itop-test.acme.org:8000
Connection: Keep-Alive


..........@Q....=..P.9.....GET
/webservices/export.php?login_mode=basic&format=csv&expression=SELECT%20Ticket&fields= HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */* 
Host: itop-test.acme.org:8000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Basic asdfasdfasdfasdf
```

Then python

```
..........@...W.@..P.9.....GET
/webservices/export.php?login_mode=basic&format=csv&expression=SELECT Ticket&fields= HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: itop-test.acme.org:8000
Connection: close
Authorization: Basic asdfasdfasdfasdf
User-Agent: Python-urllib/2.6
```

I changed the user agent for python, but that did not help. I also tried to change the `Connection`, but that did not work.

Any ideas on what is going on here? What can I try to make this work? Maybe some even understands what is going on? :)

*Edit*
It turns out that also `curl` is not working:

```
curl --user myusername:$(cat /home/dummy/private/.passwd) \
"http://${SERVER}.acme.org:8000/webservices/export.php?login_mode=basic&format=csv &expression=${SELECT_STATEMENT}&fields=${FIELDS}"
```

Same result as with python urllib2. I also tried pycurl, with no success (same result as urllib2 and curl on commandline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that only wget is capable of translating whitespace in the url into `%20`. If I replace it myself, it works. So I build my url like this

```
url = 'http://' + itop_server + \
     '.acme.org:8000/webservices/export.php?login_mode=basic&format=xml&expression='\
     + select_statement.replace(' ','%20') + '&fields=' + fields
```

which automatically replaces whitespace, and I can still write my select statements with whitespace.

Comment: Rather than encoding spaces 'by hand' in the query string, I suggest to use a python package dedicated to URL handling: `urllib`. See this post for details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9345102/5322094

Comment: That is actually what I am doing now - I was lucky enough to have had the time to refactor. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've created a library for python3 that brings the data you need very very easily. (install via `pip install itoptop`):

```
from itoptop import Itop
url = 'https://itop_server_name/webservices/rest.php'
ver = '1.3'
usr = 'user'
pwd = 'password'
itop = Itop(url, ver, usr, pwd)
ticket = Itop.schema('Ticket')

query_all = {}
query_from_steve = {'caller_name': 'Steve'}

all_tickets = ticket.find(query_all)
tickets_from_steve = ticket.find(query_from_steve)
```

If you need specific fields from iTop:

```
team_name_field = ['team_name']
team_name_from_all_tickets = ticket.find(query_all, team_name_field)

date_fields = ['start_date', 'end_date']
tickets_datefields_from_steve = ticket.find({query_from_steve, date_fields)
```

To save this in csv:

```
def to_csv(dics, filename, keys=None):
    """
    Create a CSV from a dictionary list
    :param dics: dictionary list
    :param filename: output filename
    :param keys: Optional, subset of keys. Default is all keys.
    :return: None
    """
    if not keys:
        keys = sorted(set().union(*(d.keys() for d in dics)))

    import csv
    with open(filename, 'w') as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(dics)

to_csv(all_tickets, 'all_tickets.csv')
```

If you need import csv to iTop:

```
def csv(filename):
    """
    Read CSV and make a dictionary list
    :param filename: csv
    :return: dictionary list
    """
    import csv
    return list(csv.DictReader(open(filename)))


all_tickets = csv('all_tickets.csv')
ticket.insert(all_tickets)
```

If you need update a specific field:

```
update_org_id = {'org_id' = 1}
ticket.update(query_from_steve, update_org_id)
```