# Accented Letters - Python 3.3 and Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, diacritics

So I'm using Python 3.3 and Beautiful Soup 4, just to get that out there.

What I'm trying to do is create a program that lets me input a word and it searches an online Irish/English and English/Irish dictionary, giving me the results for the word. However, Irish makes use of accented letters. I'm having issues with my code when searching for words that use these letters. All other words work, but when I try to search for an accented one, say "déan", I get

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)

Here is my code for the Irish section. All I have important before it is asking language and getting the word.

```
if language == "IRISH" or "I" or "GAEILGE" or "G":
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://breis.focloir.ie/en/fgb/"+word)
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html) # Gets your soup
    bowl = soup.findAll("div", class_="fgb entry") # Searches for div with correct entry
    for b in bowl:
        print(b.get_text(),"\n")
```

I'm pretty sure the error is with the "response" section, but I have no idea how to fix it so it incorporates the word correctly, especially since Python recognizes that "dean" doesn't equal "déan".

Comment: You have to urlencode this word, I suppose. AFAIU, in urllib there is a quote_plus function for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/python-urlencode-string

Comment: Thank you! Got it to work. Marking it as closed now.