# Python requests urlencode without sending any request

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

Is there a way to use the python Requests module to urlencode a string without sending an actual request?

This can be done with urllib as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/python-urlencode-string):

```
>>> urllib.quote_plus('string_of_characters_like_these:$#@=?%^Q^$')
'string_of_characters_like_these%3A%24%23%40%3D%3F%25%5EQ%5E%24'
```

I couldn't find any Requests documentation that shows how to achieve a comparable result.

Thanks in advance,

Wilhelm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Requests uses the standard library for these functions, and makes them available through its [`compat`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/8b5e457b756b2ab4c02473f7a42c2e0201ecc7e9/requests/compat.py) module:

```
>>> import requests.compat
>>> requests.compat.quote_plus
<function quote_plus at 0x10eb12de8>
>>> requests.compat.quote_plus('string_of_characters_like_these:$#@=?%^Q^$')
'string_of_characters_like_these%3A%24%23%40%3D%3F%25%5EQ%5E%24'
```

This module also insulates your code from Python 2/3 issues.

(as @LittleQ points out, it's also exported through the `utils` module as follows:

```
from .compat import (quote, urlparse, bytes, str, OrderedDict, unquote, is_py2,
                     builtin_str, getproxies, proxy_bypass, urlunparse,
                     basestring)
```

...and that's probably a more obvious way to call that functionality.

Answer (score 3):

In both python2 and python3:

```
import requests

quoted = requests.utils.quote('string_of_characters_like_these:$#@=?%^Q^$')
```

The quoted string would be:

```
'string_of_characters_like_these%3A%24%23%40%3D%3F%25%5EQ%5E%24'
```