# Redirect using webapp2 to capture the URL parameters

Tags: python, redirect, webapp2

I have written a code for a sign-up page asking for information like username, password and email. After the user gives correct input, the page is redirected to

> '/welcome?username=name'

I am using the self.redirect. By using the methd redirect, I am getting the the new URL as '/welcome'. How will I include the query parameter? I also want the user_name to be displayed to the redirected page like :

> Welcome name

How will I do this?
This is the class I have written to handle '/welcome'

```
class welcomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("Welcome")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),('/welcome',welcomeHandler)], debug=True)
```

Comment: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use string substitution. Suppose you are storing the username in name. Thus you need to write :

```
self.redirect("/Welcome/username="+name)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to encode it, you can use this:

```
import urllib
self.redirect('/welcome?' + urllib.urlencode({'username': name})
```

If you ever need to add more query parameters, just add them to the dictionary, as shown in [How to urlencode a querystring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to handle the user greeting like that? Either pass it as a template variable or do it as following:

```
class welcomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("Welcome %s") % username
```

Also, make sure you create a session for the user once they've signed up, otherwise you're just creating their credential but not actually logging them in.