# python requests and percent encoding of path

Tags: python, python-requests

when using python requests am I supposed to urlencode the URI manually?

```
>>> requests.get('http://example.com/increased by 10% (@tom)').url
u'http://example.com/increased%20by%2010%%20(@tom)'
```

here the `%`, `(`, `)` and `@` characters are not encoded while spaces are. what is the official way of making such request? should I wrap the path part using `urllib.quote()`?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/python-urlencode-string question. In that there is method called urllib.quote_plus. See if that one works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

`requests` will quote only unreserved characters ([code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/utils.py#L418)). % and () are reserved characters so you'd have to quote them yourself. Spaces are unreserved characters and `requests` does quote them for you. See [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for the list of reserved URI characters.

Comment: The wiki page probably isn't something you can rely on, but since you're referencing it: I don't see the space-character being a reserved character. Am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed and since it is *not* a reserved character, requests encodes/quotes it to %20.