# 400 code error when URL contains % symbol? (NGINX)

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, symbols, bad-request

How to prevent a server from returning an `error 400` code error when the URL contains `%` symbol using NGINX server?

Nginx configuration for my website:

```
....
   rewrite ^/download/(.+)$   /download.php?id=$1  last;
....
```

When I tried to get access to this URL:
http://mywebsite.net/download/some-string-100%-for-example
I got this error:

```
400 Bad Request
```

With this url :
http://mywebsite.net/download/some-string-%25-for-example
it's work fine !

Comment: Is it possible for you to show the original link? I want to test the link in my own browser

Comment: sorry it's not because it's an application hosted on my computer but i get 400 error with this string '100%' in my url, but it's work  fine with %20 string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it needs to be URL encoded first.

This will explain:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
>
> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.
>
> URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
> URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

The URL interpreter is confused to see a `%` without hexadecimals after it.

### Why would you think of solving by changing Nginx configuration???

It's impossible to solve from the server side. It's a problem from the client side.

https://headteacherofgreenfield.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/100-celebrations/

In that URL, the title is `100% Celebrations!` but the permalink is autogenerated to `100-celebrations`. It's because they know putting `100%` will cause a URL encode problem.

If even Wordpress doesn't do it your way, then why should you do it?

Comment: Try change `100%` in the URL to `100%25`. If it works, then I am right

Comment: https://headteacherofgreenfield.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/100-celebrations/ In that URL, the title is `100% Celebrations!` but the permalink is autogenerated to `100-celebrations`. It's because they know putting `100%` will cause a problem.

Comment: but your "answer it's not clear yet", wich changes i have to do ?

Comment: You have to convert your URL to a URL friendly format using a URL encode function. The function depends on which language you are using. This is for python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/python-urlencode-string

Comment: the probleme is that 400 error happened before execute php code so i can't do string encoding, so i should to do something in nginx file configuration, for example check $request_uri and replace % by empty char , really i don't know !!

Comment: You need to be clearer on what do you mean with `before execute php code`. Please update your question post with the detail of it. From what I know, it can't be solved in Nginx configuration. Even Wordpress doesn't do that. Why would you? This problem should be solved from the client side, not the server.