# Url encode using python 2.7

Tags: rest, python-2.x, httplib

```
>>> import httplib
>>> x = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost', 8080)
>>> x.connect()
>>> x.request('GET','/camera/store?fn=aaa&ts='+str.encode('2015-06-15T14:45:21.982600+00:00','ascii')+'&cam=ddd')
>>> y=x.getresponse()
>>> z=y.read()
>>> z
```

'error: Invalid format: "2015-06-15T14:45:21.982600 00:00" is malformed at " 00:00"'

And the system show me this error. As i want to encode this format to this:  2015-06-15T14%3A45%3A21.982600%2B00%3A00

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> f = { 'fn' : 'aaa', 'ts' : "2015-06-15T14:45:21.982600+00:00"}
>>> urllib.urlencode(f)
```

from:

[How to urlencode a querystring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/python-urlencode-querystring)

Comment: Just: x.request('GET','/camera/store?fn=aaa&ts='+urllib.urlencode(f)+'&cam=ddd'), also add cam and 'ddd' to the data...

Answer (score 4):

```
url = "http://example.com?p=" + urllib.quote(query)
```

it works with this!