# How can I access the data that is getting logged in Azure Application Insights using python sdk?

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a template deployed on azure which creates a resource group with various resources. These resources include an Application Insight. I want to access the latest data generated in 'event1' and 'event2' in my Application Insight using python 2.7.5.
How to do that?

I have tried using azurerm but couldn't get the data.

Comment: do you have any progress on this?

Comment: Yes I have gone through the links that you provided.
I am looking for the query formats which I think will be done soon.

Comment: It would be more easier if you nav to azure portal -> your application insights -> Logs (Analytics): write your query there, if you get the result you want, just use that query.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I got the required data through postman. But when I copy the python code from postman and run it on my linux machine, I get the following output:

{"error":{"message":"The request had some invalid properties","code":"BadArgumentError","innererror":{"code":"SyntaxError","message":"A recognition error occurred in the query.","innererror":{"code":"SYN0002","message":"Query could not be parsed at '%' on line [1,6]","line":1,"pos":6,"token":"%"}}}}

Comment: can you please try encode your url? For python 2.7, you can refer to this [SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541436/url-encode-using-python-2-7?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: When I run the same code without adding any query, it works fine. But adding query also adds '%' in the request which gives error.

Comment: I used json.dumps for the query. It doesnt give any error now but it is returning empty list. 
output: {"tables":[]}
table should contain values according to my queries.
The same code runs fine on postman.

Comment: I only have python 3.7 environment, if you don't mind, I can write a sample with python 3.7 tomorrow. Is it ok for you?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. But it worked out now. I passed the query in the url itself instead of passing it as a parameter in the GET request.
Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the data in application insights, you should use [App Insights rest api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart).

First, you should follow this [doc](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/API-key-and-App-ID) on how to get **API key** and **Application ID**.

Second, you can nav to this [link](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query), write your query to get the data you want. It will generate a get query url which you should use it for the query.

Thrid, you should use python to build a get request. And in this doc, there is an exmaple written in c#, you can try to modify it with python.

If everything is ok, you should get the data.

And if you cannot figure it out, I can provide you a python example later when I'm availabe.