# How to URL encode in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlencode

I have tried to follow [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html) but was not able to use `urlparse.parse.quote_plus()` in `Python 3`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

params = urlparse.parse.quote_plus({'username': 'administrator', 'password': 'xyz'})
```

I get

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'parse'

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You misread the documentation. You need to do two things:

1. Quote each key and value from your dictionary, and
2. Encode those into a URL

Luckily `urllib.parse.urlencode` does both those things in a single step, and that's the function you should be using.

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus

payload = {'username':'administrator', 'password':'xyz'}
result = urlencode(payload, quote_via=quote_plus)
# 'password=xyz&username=administrator'
```

Comment: It's a pity that it does not work with plain strings like PHP's function `urlencode()`. So one must have key:value pairs, which IMHO is too restrictive. For instance, I have a need to URL encode only a part of string - password in `proto://user:pass@site.com` cmd line to run duplicity backup. Python2 does work as intended though: `python2 -c "import urllib as ul; print ul.quote_plus('$KEY');"` -> where `$KEY` is supplied from bash script.

Comment: @stamster `quote_plus` is available in Python 3 the same way. `python3 -c "import urllib.parse as ul; print(ul.quote_plus('$KEY'))"`

Answer (score 101):

For Python 3 you could try using `quote` instead of `quote_plus`:

```py
import urllib.parse

print(urllib.parse.quote("http://www.sample.com/", safe=""))
```

Result:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sample.com%2F
```

Or:

```
from requests.utils import requote_uri
requote_uri("http://www.sample.com/?id=123 abc")
```

Result:

```
'https://www.sample.com/?id=123%20abc'
```

Comment: This is not Python 3 code. Unfortunately there is no quote in urllib in python3 anymore.

Comment: Try urllib.parse.quote [Edited the original post] @NiallFarrington

Comment: `from requests.utils import requote_uri` worked on Python 3.6

Comment: if that is python3 then ```print()``` require its parenthesis.

Comment: `print(urllib.parse.quote("http://www.sample.com/"))` prints `http%3A//www.sample.com/`

Comment: @AliKaraca If you want to URL encode slashes (`/`) as well, you have to pass `safe=""` as second parameter to the `quote` function. Like so:
`urllib.parse.quote("http://www.sample.com/", safe="")`

Answer (score 18):

You’re looking for `urllib.parse.urlencode`

```
import urllib.parse

params = {'username': 'administrator', 'password': 'xyz'}
encoded = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
# Returns: 'username=administrator&password=xyz'
```

Comment: This does not work for say `username` and `password` in `http://username:password@www.site.com/`

Comment: Your example uses path params, not query params. For those you need:
`
from urllib.parse import quote
resource_path = "http://{username}:{password}@www.site.com/"
path_params = dict(username='hit there', password='hi there')
for k, v in path_params.items():
    # specified safe chars, encode everything
    resource_path = resource_path.replace(
        '{%s}' % k,
        quote(str(v))
)
`