# Why I can't make a Binance order using c# with the official Binance REST API?

Tags: c#, api, binance

I am new to StackOverflow but I heard that there are awesome and helpful people who can help me out.

**My mission:**

- To find a way to make a trade calling the Binance REST API using c#
- Without dlls, using my own code (for speed update)

Now I using the Binance.API package but my bot needs to be a bit faster as its speed is not enough.
Also, it would be a great thing to be able to do that without any external sources like dlls. Isn't it?

**What I tried:**

- ***Success:*** I can call the public API without problem with *"WebRequest"* and which there **is no need** authentication.

```
WebRequest webrequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT");
WebResponse Response = webrequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

- ***Success:*** I can call the REST API without problem with *"WebRequest"* and which there **is need** authentication. *BUT only the account information.*

```
string dataQueryString = "recvWindow=15000&timestamp=" + Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds), 0).ToString();
WebRequest webrequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?" + dataQueryString + "&signature=" + BitConverter.ToString(new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tempAPI_Secret)).ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataQueryString))).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower());
webrequest.Method = "GET";
webrequest.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", tempAPI_Key);
WebResponse Response = webrequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
Response.Close();
```

- ***!!! THE PROBLEM !!!*** I can't call the ORDER REST API with *"WebRequest"* and which there **is need** authentication. I tried the code below. (*It is called the same way as the account information but with the type of POST and of course with the plus parameters needed*)

```
string dataQueryString = "symbol=BTCUSDT&side=SELL&type=LIMIT&quantity=0.00039&price=38878&newOrderRespType=RESULT&recvWindow=15000&timestamp=" + Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds), 0).ToString();
WebRequest webrequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?" + dataQueryString + "&signature=" + BitConverter.ToString(new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tempAPI_Secret)).ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataQueryString))).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower());
webrequest.Method = "POST";
webrequest.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", tempAPI_Key);
WebResponse Response = webrequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
Response.Close();
```

**The returned ERROR code:**

> 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'

I can't understand why this is not working. *(I tried to do the order with exactly these parameters from the web client manually and it was successful)*

I checked these possible problems:

- I have enough funds on my spot account
- I trying to sell more than the minimum trade amount is

There is the official Binance REST API documentation: [HERE](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md)

**I tried to google it but I couldn't find the solution even here.**

Thanks to read it and if you could help me I would really appreciate it.

If something is not clear please ask it, I will answer!

Comment: Which exact endpoint are you trying to call, from all the ones in that documentation? You can link to the specific item from the menu

Comment: @ADyson He already mentioned exact endpoint i,e. order

Comment: @JitendraPancholi but it's not our job to dig around in the documentation for that, or assume there's only one way to call it (e.g. there could be get, post, patch and delete for the same URL). As I said myself, there are multiple entries in the documentation for "order", so it wasn't clear which one was meant.

Comment: @ADyson you should not comment if you cannot even read the question carefully.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi 1) why are you bothering with this from years ago, 2) I did read the question, and if you notice, my comment clearly points out the ways in which it's still unclear as to what the OP is referring to precisely. What information from the question do you believe I've omitted to look at, specifically?

Answer (score 4):

I was literarly doing the [same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66003521/issues-placing-a-trade-with-binance-api-using-python) you are a few days ago, except I was using python. I'm also glad to see I'm not the only one who likes coding from scratch.

My solution was to  leave the url as is `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account` and instead of attaching my order parameters `symbol=BTCUSD&side=BUY&etc...` onto the url I had to instead encode and send that data through the `data` parameter of python's built in function `urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)`

I don't know C# that well so I wouldn't know how to translate my python code to C#, but I did find this [doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class) that provides an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class#example) on how to send data using a POST request. You could also take a look at my question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66055293/14644648) as another example.

Comment: Hey. Thanks to your answer your idea is greater as it is more transparent and it can look more organized. However, my problem was a bit other., Now I am able to solve, so I will update my post, and I am working on documentation which I will post. Although I will use c# maybe it will be helpful for you too.

Comment: Hey, how did you solve your problem? i have the same error for Binance order endoint.

Comment: Can you update your question and explain how did you solve your issue. Thanks!