# Why is my url encoder not working for http requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlencode

My code in Python3:

```
import requests

URL = "http://xxx.xxx.com/querytext"

try:
    text = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text)
    r = requests.get(URL, params={"text": text}, auth=("guest", "1234"))
    r_json = r.json()
except Exception:
    return None

tag_results = r_json["data"]["result"]
```

My 'text' may contain some special characters so I want to do url encoding, as shown above. However, for one testing example, if I don't use this line:

```
text = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text)
```

I can get the expected result. Otherwise, I can't. So i suspect my way of using url encoding is wrong. What's wrong exactly?

One example of the text could be '#Thisisgreat#, yes!'

Comment: can you include some examples in your post?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557606/how-to-url-encode-in-python-3

Comment: @sh.seo how to use the encoder in this format: requests.get(URL, params={"text": text}, auth=("guest", "1234"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the request docs (https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

> Requests allows you to send HTTP/1.1 requests extremely easily.
> There’s no need to manually add query strings to your URLs, or to
> form-encode your POST data. Keep-alive and HTTP connection pooling are
> 100% automatic, thanks to urllib3.

So you do not need to parse the text manually. Doing so may "double parse" it.

Comment: So you mean in my code above, i need to remove 'text = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text)'?

Comment: 'or to form-encode your POST data', Is the requests POST or GET data?

Comment: I tried your code using requestbin.com without the parsing and it worked out. Are you having any issues not having it parsed manually?

Comment: You should look at 'There’s no need to manually add query strings to your URLs'. The params are the queries.

Comment: My http service didn't return expected results, so I am suspecting to add urlencoding.  'There’s no need to manually add query strings to your URLs', yes, but the question is whether the 'text' field in the params map needs to encoded or not?

Comment: May you try using "quote" instead of "quote_plus"?

Comment: There is no 'quote' in python3?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote

Answer (score 1):

Requests [does the encoding for you](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls), so you don't need to do it manually. So you should remove the line `text = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text)`.

Comment: In the example, 'You can see that the URL has been correctly encoded by printing the URL:' there is no special characters. So I am not sure whether it needs additional encoding for special characters.

Comment: The encoding that Requests does includes encoding special characters, so there is no need to pre-encode strings that contain special characters.