# I got error message while input string into selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have no idea why the webdriver doesn't take my string argument.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
name = "Andre Silva"
headline = "Football Player and CEO"
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/index/?keywords=" + name + " " + headline + "&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER"

driver.get(url)
```

Then I got a error message:

```
  File "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/jiajiefan/data_mining/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'url' not a string
```

Comment: Your code works well on `Python 3.6.1`. Not sure about `python2.7`

Comment: This may or may not be the issue, but URLs aren't supposed to have spaces in them.  Try replacing the spaces between your keywords with `%20`.

Comment: `link = "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/index/?keywords="+ name+ ""+ headline +"&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER"` replace it

Comment: @DebanjanB, I am using python2.7. It keeps saying 'url' not a string

Comment: @JohnGordon, linkedin.com doesn't take  %20 or 09% sometimes

Comment: This might solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python

Comment: thank guys, I got this work.