# Decoding title returned by Wikipedia API for Python requests library

Tags: python, url, python-requests, urlencode, wikipedia-api

The code below queries the Wikipedia API for pages in the "Physics" category and converts the response into a Python dictionary.

```
import ast
import requests
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Physics&cmlimit=500&cmcontinue="
response = requests.get(url)
text = response.text
dict = ast.literal_eval(sourceCode)
```

Here is one of the results returned by the Wikipedia API:

```
        {
            "pageid": 50724262,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Blasius\u2013Chaplygin formula"
        },
```

The Wikipedia page that `"Blasius\u2013Chaplygin formula"` corresponds to is [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius–Chaplygin_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius%E2%80%93Chaplygin_formula).

I want to use the "title" to download pages from Wikipedia. I've replaced all spaces with underscores. But it's failing. I'm doing:

```
import requests
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius\u2013Chaplygin_formula"
response = requests.get(url)
```

This gives me:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error:
Not Found for url: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius%5Cu2013Chaplygin_formula
```

How do I change the title `Blasius\u2013Chaplygin formula` into a URL that can be successfully called by `requests`?

When I tried to insert the Wikipedia link into this question on Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow automatically converted it to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius%E2%80%93Chaplygin_formula.

When I did:

```
import requests
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius%E2%80%93Chaplygin_formula"
response = requests.get(url)
```

it was successful, so I want a library that will do a conversion like this that I can use in Python.

Comment: can you not use the wikipaedia API?

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easier you can always use some existing wrapper around Wikipedia API such as [Wikipedia-API](https://github.com/martin-majlis/Wikipedia-API).

```
import wikipediaapi
api = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')

# it will shield you from URL encoding problems
p = api.page('Blasius\u2013Chaplygin formula')
print(p.summary)

# and it can make your code shorter
physics = api.page('Category:Physics')
for p in physics.categorymembers.values():
  print(f'[{p.title}]\t{p.summary}')
```

Answer (score 0):

That `"\u2013"` is a unicode character. It gets automatically turned into an en-dash by python, but you can't put en-dashes in wikipedia links, so you have to url encode it, which is what stackoverflow did for you earlier.

You can do it yourself by using something like this:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

url = "Blasius\u2013Chaplygin_formula"
response = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + urllib.parse.quote(url))
```

[How to urlencode a querystring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python)