# Passing a variable in shell/python

Tags: python, shell, hadoop

I'm using a python script where I'm using a shell command to copy from local to hdfs.

```
import os
import logging
import subprocess


filePath = "/tmp"
keyword = "BC10^Dummy-Segment"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filePath):
    for file in files:
        if keyword in file:
            subprocess.call(["hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /tmp/BC10%5EDummy-Segment* /user/app"], shell=True)
            subprocess.call(["hadoop fs -rm /tmp/BC10%5EDummy-Segment*"], shell=True)
```

I'm seeing this error:

```
copyFromLocal: `/tmp/BC10^Dummy-Segment*': No such file or directory
rm: `/tmp/BC10^Dummy-Segment_2019': No such file or directory
```

Updated code:

```
import glob
import subprocess
import os
from urllib import urlencode, quote_plus

filePath = "/tmp"
keyword = "BC10^Dummy-Segment"

wildcard = os.path.join(filePath, '{0}*'.format(keyword))
print(wildcard)
files = [urlencode(x, quote_via=quote_plus) for x in  glob.glob(wildcard)]
subprocess.check_call(["hadoop", "fs", "-copyFromLocal"] + files + ["/user/app"])
#subprocess.check_call(["hadoop", "fs", "-rm"] + files)
```

Seeing error when I run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ming.py", line 11, in <module>
    files = [urlencode(x, quote_via=quote_plus) for x in  glob.glob(wildcard)]
TypeError: urlencode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quote_via'
```

Comment: The real file will have ```BC10^Dummy-Segment``` followed with a timestamp so I wanted to fetch all the files beginning with this keyword.

Comment: Are you sure that these files exist? Because this might simply be caused by the * symbol matching no files at all.

Comment: When you `shell=True` there is no need to pass an array, passing the command as a string would suffice

Comment: Could you post a file name (full path) that you know it's there?

Comment: You are running rm on a loop, it will remove the files at first iteration and fail at next. For your use case you don't need to loop, in fact for this a simple shell script with that  two commands would suffice

Comment: @geckos, well, there's good reason to use a list with `shell=True`, but only if someone is Doing The Right Thing and passing data out-of-band from code. `subprocess.call(['hadoop fs -copyFromLocal "$1"* "$2"', '_', os.path.join(filePath, keyword), filePath)` is an example of what that might look like; the code in the first array element can refer to literal data passed in subsequent ones.

Comment: @HuaCha, `%5E` being unescaped to `^` is a Hadoop thing, not a Python thing or a shell thing. The tags you used aren't appropriate for getting assistance on this matter.

Comment: Right -- I'm not saying that it's *wrong* to use `%5E`, just that it's a Hadoop thing, so when you use Python and shell tags, the people here can't really help.

Comment: @HuaCha, ...by contrast, if you're asking about the backtick before the string and the forward-quote after it, that's a standard-ish way to escape strings in error messages that UNIX-y tools have been conventionally doing for a very long time; it doesn't have anything to do with your actual code's behavior.

Comment: If you want to see what the shell is actually passing to the `hadoop` command, by the way,try putting `set -x;` at the front of the command you're passing to `subprocess.call()` -- you can compare that to what the same command does when prefixed by `set -x;` at an interactive command line to see if there's anything surprising going on.

Comment: @CristiFati ```/tmp/BC10^Dummy-Segment_2019``` This is the file name

Comment: @geckos Wouldn't the copyFromLocal move all the files with this keyword first and then the rm would run? Or could I just place the rm outside of the loop?

Comment: I don't really know hadoop. `hadoop fs -rm /tmp/BC10%5EDummy-Segment*` remove all files prefixed by  `/tmp/BC10%5EDummy-Segment`? If so you can't run this twice right? It will remove the files at first run a and then fail in the next.

Comment: The case here is that you're looping over the files, but you dont use `root, dirs, file` in the loop body, so, why looping at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are URL-encoding the path to pass it properly to Hadoop, but in doing so you basically hide it from the shell. There really are no files matching the wildcard `/tmp/BC10%5EDummy-Segment*` where `%` etc are literal characters.

Try handling the glob from Python instead. With that, you can also get rid of that pesky `shell=True`; and with that change, it is finally actually correct and useful to pass the commands as a list of strings (never a list of a singe space-separated string, and with `shell=True`, don't pass a list at all). Notice also the switch to `check_call` so we trap errors and don't delete the source files if copying them failed. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188 for additional rationale.)

```py
import glob
import subprocess
import os
from urllib import quote_plus

filePath = "/tmp"
keyword = "BC10^Dummy-Segment"

wildcard = os.path.join(filePath, '{0}*'.format(keyword))
files = [quote_plus(x) for x in  glob.glob(wildcard)]
subprocess.check_call(["hadoop", "fs", "-copyFromLocal"] + files + ["/user/app"])
subprocess.check_call(["hadoop", "fs", "-rm"] + files)
```

This will not traverse subdirectories; but neither would your attempt with `os.walk()` do anything actually useful if it found files in subdirectories. If you actually want that to happen, please explain in more detail what the script should do.

Comment: Hi I'm seeing this error a ```SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` with an arrow pointing to the "s" in ```subprocess.check_call(["hadoop", "fs", "-copyFromLocal"] + files + ["/user/app"])```

Comment: _I'm guessing you are URL-encoding the path to pass it properly to Hadoop, but in doing so you basically hide it from the shell. There really are no files matching the wildcard /tmp/BC10%5EDummy-Segment* where % etc are literal characters_ good catch!

Comment: @tripleee Sorry, one more error. ```from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus``` ```ImportError: No module named parse```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.6

Comment: Eww, really? You seriously should upgrade. The `urlquote` module was called something else in Python 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python seems suitably ancient.

Comment: In Python 2, use `from urllib import urlencode, quote_plus`.

Comment: (but what you really, *really* should do is switch to Python 3 instead)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I asked to upgrade but that request was shot down. Even with the updates, I'm still seeing an error with ```TypeError: urlencode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quote_via'``` Any ideas?

Comment: @tripleee At the ```files = [urlencode(x, quote_via=quote_plus) for x in  glob.glob(wildcard)]``` line, I'm seeing ```TypeError: urlencode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quote_via'``` Any ideas?

Comment: By quick googling `files = [quote_plus(x) for x in glob.glob(wildcard)]` seems to work. Updated answer. Sorry for the mess; though you should probably have been more explicit up front with the fact that you are on Python 2 (and several other things, really).