# How to add a + sign in-between two words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am rendering a URL by user input. There if user enter a string with two words I want to print the word with + in between

Example

```
key = input("Enter the product :")

URL = "http://exmaple.com/"

print (URL)

User input: iPhone 11
```

For the above code, I get a URL as "http://exmaple.com/iphone 11"

But I want to print the URL as "http://exmaple.com/iphone+11"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to urlencode a querystring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python)

Comment: `key = input("Enter the product :").strip().replace(' ','+')`?

Answer (score 2):

try encoding the key:

```
import urllib.parse
key = input("Enter the product :")
path = urllib.parse.quote_plus(key)
URL = "http://exmaple.com/{}".format(path)
print (URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution is this:

```
key = input("Enter the product :")  # product has to have exactly one space between
# otherwise you have to make additional checks
URL = "http://exmaple.com/{}".format(key.strip().replace(" ", "+"))

print(URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use `urlparse`  like below:

```py
from urllib.parse import urljoin, quote_plus
key = input("Enter the product :")
final_url = urljoin( "http://exmaple.com/", quote_plus(key))
print(final_url)

# 'http://exmaple.com/iPhone+11'
```

Refrence:

1. urllib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html
2. urljoin: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin
3. quote_plus: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus

Answer (score 0):

```
url = f"http://exmaple.com/{key.strip().replace(' ','+')}"
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work?