# Python requests option converts params to "&amp;"

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to set params on a requests.get() the url is setting the & to & and the site appears to be rejecting the request.

Here is my sample code:

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
print(r.url)
```

```
https://httpbin.org/get?key1=value1&amp;key2=value2
```

expecting:

```
https://httpbin.org/get?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Comment: this is working fine for me

Comment: Try encoding the URL 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python

Answer (score 0):

My setup and version of the Requests library does not do what you are saying that your setup is doing.  What I get as output when I run your code is:

```
https://httpbin.org/get?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

What's particularly interesting is that this sample code comes straight from the library's own documentation:

> https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

And right there, they show what you should get from this code:

```
>>> print(r.url)
https://httpbin.org/get?key2=value2&key1=value1
```

It's a bit strange that in their version, the order of the two parameters is reversed, but since a map implies no ordering of its contents, I think that's ok.  This is otherwise the same thing that I get...no encoded ampersands.

So why you are getting a result with the ampersands encoded, I can't say, but it seems that somehow, your configuration is other than the usual in that you're getting other than the usual result.

Comment: It's not strange at all that the order changes, dictionaries (on older versions of python) do not keep the ordering of keys.

Comment: @LtWorf - I think it's a little strange in that it means that the implementation must have changed.  But yeah, it's not overly surprising or interesting.

Comment: It has changed. But before you could not do any assumptions at all on the order they would take. It might also happen that running twice the same program it'd be different. On more recent versions of python they changed and it keeps the order in which they are added.

Comment: Is there a way to configure it? I just ran the out of the box version of requests. (
2.24.0)

Comment: Not that I know of.  I wouldn't expect that to be an option.  That's why this is so strange.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - I've just upgraded to requests 2.25.0 and also get the encoded version...