# How do I urlencode all the characters in a string, including safe characters?

Tags: python, urlencode

Using Python, how would I encode all the characters of a string to a URL-encoded string?

As of now, just about [every answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607708/11985743) eventually references the same methods, such as `urllib.parse.quote()` or `urllib.parse.urlencode()`. While these answers are technically valid (they follow the required specifications for encoding special characters in URLs), I have not managed to find a single answer that describes how to encode other/non-special characters as well (such as lowercase or uppercase letters).

How do I take a string and encode every character into a URL-encoded string?

Comment: Could I ask what you need it for? I'm sure there's a good reason, but I want to make sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: While pentesting some websites, I have found that double-encoding all the characters in a query can bypass Web Application Firewalls. I've been using a website to do the encoding work for me, but I finally sought a programmatic way to encode the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/Paradoxis/6336c2eaea20a591dd36bb1f5e227da2) reveals a very nice answer to this problem. The final function code is as follows:

```py
def encode_all(string):
    return "".join("%{0:0>2x}".format(ord(char)) for char in string)
```

Let's break this down.

The first thing to notice is that the return value is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) (`... for char in string`) wrapped in a `str.join` call (`"".join(...)`). This means we will be performing an operation for each character in the string, then finally joining each outputted string together (with the empty string, `""`).

The operations performed per character can be broken down into the following:

- `ord(char)`: Convert each character to the corresponding number.
- `"%{0:0>2x}".format(...)`: Convert the number to a hexadecimal value. Then, format the hexadecimal value into a string (with a prefixed `"%"`).

When you look at the whole function from an overview, it is converting each character to a number, converting that number to hexadecimal, then jamming all the hexadecimal values into a string (which is then returned).

Comment: You don't need to format twice. `"%{0:0>2x}".format(ord(char))`

Comment: Is this designed for non-ASCII characters? For example, zero-padding to two spaces doesn't really make sense for codepoints greater than U+FF. I think you'd be better off encoding first, then URL-quoting.

Comment: @wjandrea it is not; but [neither are the applicable standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data), which basically just expect you to muddle through somehow.

Comment: If it helps, here's a decoder: `''.join(chr(int(c, 16)) for c in re.findall(r'%([0-9A-Fa-f]{2,6})', string))`