# Selenium open the webpage forcing the url lowercase

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i'm runnig this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.get("https://www.vivaticket.com/it/search?categoryId=10&provinceCode=BO")
```

The open page is all lowercase "https://www.vivaticket.com/it/search?categoryid=10&provincecode=bo" and finds no results.

Do you have an idea how to deal with it?
Thx for help

Comment: If you know that the provinceCode has to be uppercase (as is apparently the situation) then where is the problem?

Comment: I can't manually change the provinceCode on the openpage every time :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can bypass this using url-encoding:

```py
def encode(string):
    return "".join("%{0:0>2}".format(format(ord(char), "x")) for char in string)

province = "BO"
url = "https://www.vivaticket.com/it/search?categoryid=10&provincecode="+encode(province)

driver.get(url)
```

In your case, `%42%4F` stands for `BO`.

[resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67629249/20443541)

Comment: Great anticipation +1

Answer (score 0):

This is the site doing that on first browse for some reason. What I found that works is to just navigate twice.

```
String url = "https://www.vivaticket.com/it/search?categoryId=10&provinceCode=BO";
driver.get(url);
driver.get(url);
// proceed with your script
```

The second navigation keeps the proper capitalization.