# Convert string to google search link in python

Tags: python, google-search

I need to convert any string to a google search link. For example:

```
"google search link"  -> https://www.google.com/search?q=google+search+link&oq=google+search+link&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l9.3500j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

Is there any python library or function for this conversion.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution for your sample string:

```
my_str = "google search link"
out_link = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + '+'.join(my_str.split(' '))
```

You might be interested in deleting/handling special characters too

Answer (score 1):

```py
import urllib.parse; 
quary = "how to Convert string to google search link in python"
safe_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(quary)
print("https://www.google.com/search?q="+safe_string)
```

[How to urlencode a querystring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python)