# How to use semicolons in html/css in a curl PUT to the canvas api

Tags: python, html, css, curl, canvas-lms

I am new to curl and I am using it with the canvas api and python to update a discussions description like so

```
subprocess.call(['curl', '-X', 'PUT', url, '-F', title, '-F', desc, '-H', auth])
```

this is successful however I get

```
Warning: skip unknown form field: "><tbody><tr><td style='border: 1px solid
```

when I put a `;` in `desc`. `desc` is HTML and CSS.

Example:

This works

```
desc = 'message = <table style = "width: 30%">...</table>'
```

This does not work

```
desc = 'message = <table style="width: 30%;">...</table>'
```

notice the `;` after `30%` which is triggering the warning

I would like to be able to do `<table style="width: 30%; border: 1px solid;"><tbody>...` but since I currently cant have `;`'s I am unable to do so.

How can I use semicolons inside of my curl call like this?

Comment: You need to percent-encode the `=` inside the parameter value.

Comment: Why are you using `curl` instead of the `requests` module? It will take care of parameter encoding for you.

Comment: I am working off of my professors, old code and he used curl, I will look into the requests module thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python for the way to encode the query string.