# Python request error “ requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError” with a specific value

Tags: python

I have this code in python to make requests:

```
import requests
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('C:/asg/ftpfiles/data.json') as json_file:
    dataparse = json.load(json_file)

iPartNumber = dataparse['distributornumsku']

  

r = requests.get('https://online.xxx.com/xxx/items/' + str(iPartNumber), auth=('test@test.com', 'test')).json()
with open('itemdatasku.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(r, json_file)
```

The data JSON I’m reading is:

```
{"distributornumsku": "RFBB5-56C40K2/32"}
```

However the script crashes with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\asg\ftpfiles\api.py", line 28, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://online.xxx.com/xxx/items/' + str(iPartNumber), auth=('test@test.com', 'test')).json()
  File "C:\Users\serverqnapwin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The error was because I’m sending the value **RFBB5-56C40K2/32** and there is the problem maybe the “/“ or who knows is causing the problem/ If I use any other value offered than **RFBB5-56C40K2/32** it works.

The problem is the code is sending incorrectly the request at difference of other cases for example. The script is sending:

```
https://online.xxx.com/xxx/items/RFBB5-56C40K2/32
```

As you see the last “/32” is the problem is not sending as a whole “RFBB5-56C40K2/32”. How can I avoid the /32 that it splits after the “/“ as if was another subdirectory after the “/“?

What could be the problem and how can I fix the script to avoid this error?

Comment: Are you sure that's what the API is returning? Try using `.contents()` to see the actual value returned by the API.

Comment: I detected the problem. I updated the main question the problem is that the “/32” at the end of the element. The “32” is taken as a subdirectory. That is the problem and I don’t know how to solve.

Comment: The slash isn't being added by the script, it's in `iPartNumber`. What is the correct URL?

Comment: If you want to remove `/32`, use `iPartNumber.split('/')[0]`

Comment: The problem is we need to search RFBB5-56C40K2/32 complete if I remove the /32 is incorrect the search. I just wanna know how to send the www and that includes the /32

Comment: I don't understand. If that's what you need to search, why do you say that `/32` is the problem?

Comment: Oh is simple. Because, the link to request with get is “ https://online.xxx.com/xxx/items/RFBB5-56C40K2/32” as you can see check at the end the ‘/32’ instead to search whole by logical is searching in subdirectory 32. This is the link ‘https://online.xxx.com/xxx/items/RFBB5-56C40K2/’ and it searches for 32 only that is the problem

Comment: It must search “https://online.xxx.com/xxx/items/RFBB5-56C40K2/32“ Literally

Comment: I'm totally lost. I can't see the distinction you're making. HTTP doesn't have directories and subdirectories. The server can interpret the URL however it wants.

Comment: Either the URL should end with `/32` or not. Which do you want? If you want to search for `32` but not put `/32` in the link, where is it supposed to go instead?

Comment: Put backticks around the URL in comments so it won't format it as a clickable link.

Comment: ‘`https://online.xxx.com/xxx/items/RFBB5-56C40K2/32`’ What it does this is search

Comment: That's the URL you're sending with `requests.get()`. What should it be instead?

Comment: The web page ‘ https://online.xxx.com/xxx/items/ ‘ must accept the request to search for item ‘RFBB5-56C40K2/32’ apparently the error is it takes /32 as a subdirectory of the server and is not searching whole ‘RFBB5-56C40K2/32‘. It truncates the search as i searching for a directory ‘32’ inside the server that obvious it doesn’t exist

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to encode the `/` character somehow if it's part of a search string. This would be something specific to that website. Or maybe you can use `%2F` in the URL.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python for how to encode it.

Comment: I solved the issue. The %2F not worked. But what worked is send the value like this ‘ https://online.xxx.com/xxx?items=RFBB5-56C40K2/32 ‘ By any reason the server accepted the ‘?items=‘ just for the values with ‘/‘ for the values without ‘/‘ no need to enter ‘?items=‘. Then is solved now with ‘?items=“. Thank you anyway.

Comment: It's for exactly the reason you said. In the path part of a URL, `/` is a separator. But it has no special meaning in the query string.