# python3 Error using requests: URL with spaces

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to make an API call to the Prolin Smart Suite API. Using Postman I can do it successfully, the call has to look like this:

```
https://myserver.mydomain.net:5181/odata/ConfigurationItems?$filter=Searchcode eq 'myparameter'
```

Trying to do this in Python gives me the following error:

> INFO - 2024-01-10 08:10:12,540 - ci is myparameter
> INFO - 2024-01-10 08:10:12,540 - ci_url is http://myserver.mydomain.net:5181/odata/ConfigurationItems? $filter=Searchcode eq 'myparameter'
> ERROR - 2024-01-10 08:10:12,540 - Error during request: Invalid URL 'myparameter': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://myparameter?

This is my code:

```
ci = 'myparameter'
logging.info('ci is '+ci)
ci_url = api_url + f"/ConfigurationItems?$filter=Searchcode eq '{ci}'"
logging.info('ci_url is '+ci_url)

# Get responsible workgroup
def get_responsible_workgroup(ci_url):
    try:
        ci_url = ci_url
        ci_response = requests.get(ci_url)
        #ci_response.raise_for_status()  # Check for HTTP errors
        logging.info("ci_response: "+ci_response.text)
        return ci_response
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"Error during request: {e}")
        return None
        
resp_wg = get_responsible_workgroup(ci)
logging.info('resp_wg is '+str(resp_wg))
```

I also tried to replace the quotes and the spaces with the according URL encoding (%27 and %20) but this gives the same error.

Further I tried to use the ChatGPT solution but it did not work either:

```
# Assuming base_url is defined somewhere in your code
base_url = "http://myserver.mydomain.net:5181/odata"

ci = "myparameter"
ci_sanitized = urllib.parse.quote(ci, safe='')
logging.info('ci is ' + ci)

api_endpoint = '/ConfigurationItems'
filter_parameter = "$filter=Searchcode eq '{}'".format(ci_sanitized)
ci_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, "{}?{}".format(api_endpoint, filter_parameter))
logging.info('ci_url is ' + ci_url)

try:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(ci_url) as response:
        data = response.read()
        # Process the response data as needed
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print("Error during request: {}".format(e))
```

Comment: Looks like you're just using `urllib` rather than `requests` there.  Requests has a much nicer API where you can pass the parameters as a dictionary and it handles encoding them correctly for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python

Comment: Are you sure you have copy-pasted the output of the program correctly? In the `ci_url is` line, there shouldn't be a space before `$filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ci_url = api_url + f"/ConfigurationItems?$filter=Searchcode eq '{ci}'"
```

with

```
import urllib.parse
ci_url = api_url + "/ConfigurationItems?$filter=" + urllib.parse.quote_plus(f"Searchcode eq '{ci}'")
```

This will replace the spaces in the URL with `+` signs, and it will prevent the RequestException (*No schema supplied*).

If it doesn't work for you, please extend the question with the output of the program after this change.

---

There is an even more robust solution, passing URL parameters as `requests.get(params={...})`, and thus letting *requests* build the URL for you. To do that, replace the `requests.get(...)` line in your program with:

```
ci_response = requests.get(api_url + "/ConfigurationItems", params={
    "$filter": f"Searchcode eq '{ci}'"})
```

Answer (score 0):

We ruled out multiple problems in the code. As intended the requests library was used wrong. Also we passed only the ci but not the ci_url to the function.

The working code looks like this:

```
ci = 'myparameter'
logging.info('ci is '+ci)
ci_url = api_url + f"/ConfigurationItems?$filter=Searchcode eq '{ci}'"
logging.info('ci_url is '+ci_url)

# Get responsible workgroup
def get_responsible_workgroup(ci_url, access_token):
    try:
        headers = {'Authorization': access_token,'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        ci_response = requests.get(ci_url,headers=headers)
        #ci_response.raise_for_status()  # Check for HTTP errors
        logging.info("ci_response: "+ci_response.text)
        endsession = requests.post('http://myserver.mydomain.net:5181/connect/endsession', headers={'Authorization': access_token,'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        return json.loads(ci_response.text)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"Error during request: {e}")
        return None



resp_wg = get_responsible_workgroup(ci_url, token)
logging.info('resp_wg is '+str(resp_wg))
```

Comment: this doesn't seem like an answer, and has its own issues.  you can't include any body with a GET request, so passing a content-type header isn't right as it can't be there.  why have you commented out the `raise_for_status()` line? that's normally a useful check.  finally, why not just use `ci_response.json()` method to get the response as JSON rather than using the `json` module manually.