how to create a hyper link in python

I am new to Python and URLs
I am trying something like this in python. I need to add a string to the URL can some one please help here. If we can convert the string to URL please suggest me. I have executed above script in python.
I am looking for a hyperlink for a string in python.

What's wrong with what you have?

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

@Barmar It appears that the ?[]=char is not part of the hyperlink. Only an image would show that

That's more related to the way your terminal emulator is automatically detecting URL in output. Try url-encoding the query string, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python

This isn't really a Python question. The REPL (PyCharm?) is determining how to highlight the link

It should be less of a problem if you include url in HTML that you generate, e.g. with Flask.

The second ? in the URL is invalid it has to be URL encoded as%3F. The same applies to the [].

You're not clear on what you want (or misinterpreting something), but there's a chance what you want is the Python urllib.parse library.

The []=char query param should use & if it is a new parameter, then the [] must be url encoded.
You can use urllib.parse.urlencode to add query parameters in the correct format.
This fully highlights as a hyperlink in PyCharm console
import urllib
'https://example.com' + '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode({'param': 'specialanother', '[]': 'char'})
# 'https://example.com?param=specialanother&%5B%5D=char'


How to get [] in the URL? instead of %5B%5D

@Siya Those characters aren't supported in urls. They need to be encoded
