# Order of keys in dictionaries in old versions of Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Code:

```
d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
l = d.keys()

print l
```

This prints `['a', 'c', 'b']`. I'm unsure of how the method `keys()` determines the order of the keywords within `l`. However, I'd like to be able to retrieve the keywords in the "proper" order.

The proper order of course would create the list `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Comment: If Python dictionaries are like most, they're actually hash tables.  Among other things, that means the order of the keys isn't guaranteed or even specified.  In particular, it wouldn't remember the order in which keys are added.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is python ordering my dictionary like so?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526125/why-is-python-ordering-my-dictionary-like-so)

Comment: @cHao: This essentually means that your program will be indeterministic if you loop over the elements in a dictionary?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: I wouldn't go that far; there's still very predictable behavior there.  Each full iteration sees exactly one of each key/value pair.  And in *most* languages, you'll even see them in the same order each time.  Unless the docs guarantee a particular order, though, you shouldn't count on it being the order you want.  (Some languages (like Perl) will actually randomize the order a bit -- allegedly for security reasons, but i think it's really just to shake you loose from the habit of relying on unspecified behavior.  :)  I don't *think* Python is quite that evil, but eh...)

Comment: The order will be the same providing the dict has not been modified.
From the manual:
"If items(), keys(), values(), iteritems(), iterkeys(), and itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond. This allows the creation of (value, key) pairs using zip(): pairs = zip(d.values(), d.keys())."

Comment: This isn't working for me, at least not in python 3.4. I'm creating a simple 4-key dictionary and immediately loop over with .keys(), and the order is lost.

Comment: python 2.7.10: >>> d = {'what':1, 'the':2, 'heck':3, 'is':4, 'this':5} 
>>> d.keys()
['this', 'what', 'heck', 'the', 'is']

Comment: @sfranky I think what steveayre meant is that the order is the same between what you obtain using the different methods mentioned, not the same as the ordrer in which the elements were written.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You could use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (requires Python 2.7) or higher.

Also, note that `OrderedDict({'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3})` won't work since the `dict` you create with `{...}` has already forgotten the order of the elements. Instead, you want to use `OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])`.

As mentioned in the documentation, for versions lower than Python 2.7, you can use [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) recipe.

Comment: Keep in mind, the order of an OrderedDict is the *insertion* order; the keys will only come out in alphabetical order if you inserted them that way.

Comment: it's what he *showed* as a simplified example; it may or may not have any relation to how he actually plans to use it. I have previously encountered people who expected OrderedDict to return arbitrary insertions in sorted order, and so I felt I should point this out.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the author was looking for a dictionary preserving the *insertion order*. The key order is generally much more important and it can be achieved with a self-balancing binary search tree. In C++, we have std::set for that. In python, apparently, there's no such thing (built-in).

Answer (score 215):

### Python 3.7+

In Python [3.7.0](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html) the insertion-order preservation nature of [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) objects [has been declared](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) to be an official part of the Python language spec. Therefore, you can depend on it.

### Python 3.6 (CPython)

As of Python 3.6, for the CPython implementation of Python, dictionaries [maintain insertion order](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) by default. This is considered an implementation detail though; you should still use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want insertion ordering that's guaranteed across other implementations of Python.

### Python >=2.7 and <3.6

Use the [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class when you need a `dict` that 
remembers the order of items inserted.

Answer (score 53):

```
>>> print sorted(d.keys())
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Use the [sorted function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted), which sorts the iterable passed in.

The `.keys()` method returns the keys in an arbitrary order.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want the original order and it wasn't sorted.

Comment: If you sort once, this is good.  If you sort inside a loop you're better off with a treap or red-black tree or something - these are available on Pypi.

Answer (score 13):

From http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html:

"The keys() method of a dictionary object returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order (if you want it sorted, just apply the sorted() function to it)."

Comment: This phrase is no longer there.

Answer (score 12):

Just sort the list when you want to use it.

```
l = sorted(d.keys())
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the order does not matter as the dictionary is hashmap. It depends on the order how it is pushed in:

```py
s = 'abbc'
a = 'cbab'

def load_dict(s):
    dict_tmp = {}
    for ch in s:
        if ch in dict_tmp.keys():
            dict_tmp[ch]+=1
        else:
            dict_tmp[ch] = 1
    return dict_tmp

dict_a = load_dict(a)
dict_s = load_dict(s)
print('for string %s, the keys are %s'%(s, dict_s.keys()))
print('for string %s, the keys are %s'%(a, dict_a.keys()))
```

output:
    for string abbc, the keys are dict_keys(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    for string cbab, the keys are dict_keys(['c', 'b', 'a'])

Comment: Dictionary in python are insertion ordered only from version 3.6+ [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)