# How to use non exact match for items within data frame in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have Dict -
test_dict = {'EU6XNAS' : '23TEST1'}
print(test_dict.get('EU6XNAS')) is giving me o/p = 23TEST1 which is correct.

I wanted to get same O/P or Value if I search dictionary with first 3 char of String.
something like test_dict.get('EU6') --> Currently It will give me None.
Any other Method can i use in python?

Basically I wanted to have same o/p as "like" in sql rather than '=' exact match

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066603/fastest-way-to-search-python-dict-with-partial-keyword

Comment: You can use startswith method available in string.

    test_dict = {'EU6XNAS': '23TEST1'}
    for key in test_dict.keys():  
        if key.startswith('EU6'):
            print(test_dict[key])

Output:

    23TEST1

Answer (score 0):

You can use startswith method available in string.

```
test_dict = {'EU6XNAS': '23TEST1'}
for key in test_dict.keys():  
    if key.startswith('EU6'):
        print(test_dict[key])
```

Output:

```
23TEST1
```

Comment: This works fine however partial match on data dictionary with large size is very slow. Any other solution?