# Does "for key in dict" in python always iterate in a fixed order?

Tags: python, dictionary

Does the python code

```
for key in dict:
    ...
```

, where `dict` is a dict data type, always iterate in a fixed order with regrard to `key`? For example, suppose `dict={"aaa":1,"bbb",2}`, will the above code always first let `key="aaa"` and then `key="bbb"` (or in another fixed order)? Is it possible that the order is random? I am using python 3.3 in ubuntu 13 and let's assume this running environment doesn't change. Thank you.

add one thing: during multiple runs, the variable `dict` remains unchanged, i.e., generate once and read multiple times.

Comment: Orders of dict keys is random, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/key-order-in-python-dicionaries

Comment: you can try [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: @alexvassel: The order is unordered, but not random (for it is given by the implementation of the dict).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Intrinsically, a dictionary has no order in which it stores it keys. So you can not rely on the order. (I wouldn't assume the order to be unchanged even when the environment is identical).

One of the few reliable ways:

```
for key in sorted(yourDictionary.keys()):
    # Use as key and yourDictionary[key]
```

**EDIT**: Response to your comment:
Python does not store keys in a random fashion. All the documentation says is that, **you should not rely on this order**. It depends on the implementation how the keys are ordered. What I will say here about your question is: If you are relying on this order, you are probably doing something wrong. In general you should/need not rely on this at all. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot one thing that may be important and I add it in the original post. In my understanding, to be random needs more work, if dict remains unchanged, does its internal structure still keep varying all the time?

Comment: Yes, to be random does need more work. It isn't random, but it's not in any regular order that you can rely on.

Comment: My question is restricted to only one fixed implementation, fixed running environment. If that's fixed, that's enough for me. Now may I have a positive answer to my question?

Comment: I have a particular program with a dict that gives the same order every time, *in one run*.  The next time I run, with the same data, the order is different.

Comment: update:this answer is right,but something is outdate,look this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007169/8026780

Answer (score 5):

```
CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary 
order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and 
depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.
```

For more info:http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

What's more, You could use [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to make the order fixed.

Comment: so, if I restricted myself to one python implementation and the variable remains unchanged since it's created, the order should be fixed, right? Because I think to change the key's order needs computer's extra work.

Comment: yes, the order will be fixed if the dictionary has no insertions and deletions.