# How are values sorted when using row.values() on an SFrame row?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, dataframe, graphlab

**How are the values sorted when I use row.values() in an `graphlab.SFrame` row?**

For example:

```
import graphlab as gl
x = gl.SFrame({'X200':[1,2,3], 'X100':[4,5,6], 'X1': [7,8,9]})
row = x[0] # first row
print row.values()
```

[out]:

```
[ 7, 4, 1]
```

**So it seems like they are sorted by the key / column names, but is that always true?** Any pointers to documentation from python dictionary or SFrame will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No the `row.values()` will not return a sorted list since `row` is a python  dictionary and it is unsorted.

To prove the point:

```
>>> x = gl.SFrame({'X1': ['foo', 'bar', 'blah'], 'X3':[1,2,3], 'X2':[4,5,6]})
>>> x[0].values()[1:]
[1, 'foo']
```

It seems like to get a sorted values, you would have to do some key sorting first:

```
>>> _, v = zip(*sorted(x[0].items())[1:])
>>> v
(4, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Python dictionary issue (see [Key Order in Python Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/key-order-in-python-dictionaries)). In python, the `.values()` method returns values in arbitrary order. A row of the SFrame is a dictionary.