# How can I get the keys in a dictionary in the order that they appear in the dictionary?

Tags: python

for example, let's say I have this dictionary:

```
Dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
```

I want to get a list like this: ['Name', 'Age', 'Class'] and not in other order

Comment: By writing `['Name', 'Age', 'Class']`.

Comment: What's wrong with Dict.keys()?

Comment: This was just an example. The point is that in the problem I am working on I don't know the names of any of the keys

Comment: instead of `Dict` if you go with `collections.OrderedDict` it can give always same order.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered data structures. If the order matters to you, use a `collections.OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: Dict.keys() may return the keys in a different order. Maybe not for this example. But in general. Is not exactly as in the order it appears in the dict

Comment: @Caterina I think you should have a look a at the available ordered version of a dictionary, you can read this in here: [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). @StefanPochmann why even bother commenting this? It was obviously just an example.

Comment: Is there a way to convert an ordinary Dict to an Ordered Dict?

Comment: @Caterina I doubt it. I believe using a tuple to store the data first works. Since the normal dict does not remember the order of elements, even if you try to convert it to an orderedDict, the order will be wrong.

Comment: You should never be relying on the iteration order of `dict` - if `dict.keys()` doesn't return the same order as `dict` itself that's a *feature*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try from this source: [Key Order in Python Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/key-order-in-python-dictionaries)

```
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

Sadly, `OrderedDict({'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3})` won't work because The `{}` has already forgotten order of the elements.

Your code would be:

```
Dict = OrderedDict([('Name', 'Zara'), ('Age', 7), ('Class', 'First)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are inherently unordered; the order of the keys is not defined. There's no way to recover the order that you wrote them down in.

If you need an ordered version of a dictionary, look into [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) from collections.